# How do I set PATH variables for all users on a server?

Tags: software-installation, environment-variables, latex, manpage

I just finished installing [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/) for my company's Ubuntu server that we all SSH into to use. At the end of the install it says this:

```
Add /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/doc/man to MANPATH, if not dynamically determined.

Add /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/doc/info to INFOPATH.

Most importantly, add /usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/x86_64-linux to your PATH for current and future sessions.
```

How do I do this so that these variables are set for all users on the system? (And yes, I have sudo permissions).

Comment: @geirha's answer (with Rob's comment on MANPATH) resolves this except for the INFOPATH variable.  Though I imagine it is not often used by users(?), does anyone know the correct location to set that? Should it also be `/etc/environment ` ?

Comment: @jgbelacqua afaik Debian and some other Linux distros use it but not Ubuntu. Or at least thats the best I could gather frm searching on google for an hour.

Comment: When you installed TeXlive 2010, it should have asked you if you wanted to create symlinks for all the binaries. If you had said yes, this wouldn't have been an issue at all.

Comment: @frabjous It never asked me. The only command I ever gave it was "i" in the beginning to initiate the installation. Anyways, after setting the variables, it all works perfectly.

Comment: There wasn't a menu with other options at that point? If not, you must have used a different installer than the normal one [(here)](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html).

Comment: @frabjous That IS the installer I used (grabbed via wget too).

Comment: You must have missed the menu then.

Comment: @frabjous Again, I was only prompted once at which point I entered "i" as recommended in the installation section of the documentation.

Comment: There are other things you can press there besides i; there's a whole menu, one of which is to add the symlinks.

Comment: @frabjous: The symlink option seems to be now missing from the installer. I installed TeXLive 2011 today and could find it anymore. I installed TeXLive in multiple versions at least a dozen times before, so I wondered why it isn't there anymore.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You add those to `/etc/environment`.

It likely already has a line for `PATH`, so you just append `:/usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/x86_64-linux` to the end of that. Then add two new lines for MANPATH and INFOPATH.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables.

After editing `/etc/environment`, log out and back in, and check that e.g. `echo "$MANPATH"` outputs the value you added.

Comment: In the end I also had to edit /etc/manpath.config. Thanks.

Comment: I've deleted my answer, as this appears to be a better choice.   According to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariablesSystem-wide  `/etc/environment` is the place for "Environment variable settings that affect the system as a whole (rather then just a particular user) [...]"  
`/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash.bashrc` are listed as 'Not recommended'

Comment: Annoyingly doesn't work for root!

Answer (score 10):

Add these default PATH to `/etc/profile`. It will work for bash and sh. **Bash** is default in Ubuntu.

```
PATH=$PATH:<new path you need to add>
```

`echo $SHELL` can be used to determine the shell of current user or can be viewed from `/etc/passwd` file.

Alternatively you can include it in `/etc/environment` as well.
Here you can just add the PATH at the end of PATH statement.

Comment: I opened up etc/profile in vim and there was nothing regarding PATH in it. Thanks for the reply just the same.

Comment: The order of execution of files is /etc/environment -> /etc/profile -> /etc/bash.bashrc -> /home/<user>/.profile -> /home/<user>/.bashrc

Comment: editing /etc/profile path variable could damage system and its better to avoid. specially when you are connecting to remote host via ssh.