# "command not found" when running a script via cron

Tags: cron

I want to run my script in crontab, but I have some problems...

In my script I run this command:

```
db2 connect to myDB2
```

This works fine when I run this as **db2inst1** user, but when I run this script in **db2inst1 crontab**, I get this:

> db2: command not found.

How can I solve this?

Comment: better to add to environment as explained here https://askubuntu.com/a/24944/1150615

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To avoid having to type the absolute path to a command, shells introduced the `$PATH` environment variable, each directory is separated by a `:` and searches are done from left to right. `cron` often clears the whole environment, including this `$PATH` variable. Therefore, the script may behave differently in your cron compared to the behavior in the shell.

#### Use absolute paths

Run `which db2` as `db2inst1` user to get the full path for the `db2` program. If the output is `/usr/bin/db2`, your cron command would look like:

```
/usr/bin/db2 connect to myDB2
```

#### Set the PATH variable

Run `echo "$PATH"` as `db2inst1` user to get the `$PATH` variable and make sure this variable is available in your cron script too. For example, if the output was `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`, you would put the next line in the top of your shell script:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
```

Answer (score 18):

As answered in https://askubuntu.com/a/23438/227839, you should set `PATH` in your shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"

# rest of script follows
```

or in the crontab file, which will apply to all cron jobs:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
0 1 * * * db2 connect to myDB2
```

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful!

Comment: Setting the path inside `crontab` was exactly what it needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You must define what **db2**  and **myDB2** are, otherwise use the absolute location of '*file*' or '*application*' which want to run.

Example:

```
/bin/rm /home/ubuntu/a.txt
```