# Is there a standard place for placing custom Linux scripts?

Tags: scripts, directory

I am developing a set of scripts, which I want to be present for all users, when I set up a server. But I don't want them in the standard locations like `/usr[/local]/[bin]`,`[sbin]` etc.

Is there some existing convention for where such scripts should be placed?

Comment: For those who may be interested there is an old usenet thread here, https://vb.serverknecht.de/showthread.php?s=a02033e4f14d95407469b81ee34ce870&t=86454&page=1&pp=15, which leads to something more direct http://www.giwersworld.org/computers/linux/linux-file-system.html

Answer (score 74, accepted):

As far as I know there is no place for custom Linux scripts. The directory that should be used for custom install is the `/opt` directory so it would be the safest option to place them there.
But keep in mind that for a script to be able to be used without the full path you need it to be included in the PATH variable.

If you need help changing the `PATH` variable for all users you can check [How do I set PATH variables for all users on a server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24937/how-do-i-set-path-variables-for-all-users-on-a-server) which refers you to the `/etc/environment` file to configure this.

If your concern is to avoid clashes but you don't want to add another route to the PATH variable you could use `/usr/local/bin`. In my server installation it doesn't have any file  so that it could be a easy work-around.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 60):

`/usr/local/bin` seems to be the conventional place, and this directory should be empty on a fresh installs.

*Source:* The [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/308048/22949) on this question:

- [Differences between /bin, /sbin, /usr/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/sbin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308045/differences-between-bin-sbin-usr-bin-usr-sbin-usr-local-bin-usr-local)

Comment: This always throws me off - would a script (i.e., a non-binary file) go into `bin`? `etc`? `opt`? sigh.

Comment: Once you stop making distinction between binary executable and script you will get your doubts addressed instantly :)

Answer (score 13):

You could place the scripts in `/opt/bin` and add the location to the [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29).

**See:**

1. [Linux path environment variable](http://linuxconfig.org/linux-path-environment-variable)
2. [Permanently add a directory to shell PATH](http://linuxconfig.org/permanently-add-a-directory-to-shell-path)

   For global use in:

   ```
   /etc/bash.bashrc
   ```

   or

   ```
   /etc/profile
   ```

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 there is no `/opt/bin` directory anymore so you have to create it first. In this case you might as well create `/usr/local/scripts` and put that in $PATH.

Answer (score 7):

There's also `~/bin`, which acts like `/usr/local/bin`, but for just one user. To enable it, create the `~/bin` directory, log out and log back in.

Comment: If the script/executable is only for one user, `~/.local/bin` is a good place, as discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36871/where-should-a-local-executable-be-placed).

Answer (score 6):

There are several places you *could* put these, typically I place them in `/opt/` and update PATH for each user (or globally in `/etc/bash.bashrc`) so it's available to users. `/opt/` is more or less designed for what you're looking to do.