# How do I install "z" script?

Tags: command-line, software-installation

How do I install the shell ["z" script directory jumper](https://github.com/rupa/z) on Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the `z` [readme](https://github.com/rupa/z/blob/master/README), after [line 50](https://github.com/rupa/z/blob/master/README#L48), it says:

> Installation:
>
> Put something like this in your $HOME/.bashrc or $HOME/.zshrc:
>
> ```
> . /path/to/z.sh
> ```
>
> cd around for a while to build up the db.

You need to download the `z.sh` file to a directory of your choosing, then tell your `.bashrc` where it is, so your terminal can find it. (The same applies for z-shell, which is just another shell system.) Then, after you use bash for a while, `z` will know your favorite locations.

Answer (score 17):

You can download and add to `*rc` files using command line as so

```sh
# Download to latest to home dir
wget "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rupa/z/master/z.sh" -O "~/z.sh"

# Add to .bashrc
echo "source /path/to/z.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
# Add to .zshrc
echo "source /path/to/z.sh" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: @VolkerSiegel There is no link in this answer at all, so your comment isn't very helpful. David: It is true however that your answer doesn't provide much explanation. I see the shell comments, but could you expand on those in the answer itself? Thanks.

Comment: @Seth Yes, I asked on meta related to handling this as "link only", and learned something: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11980/should-i-flag-pure-shell-command-answers-as-link-only-answer I mixed up flagging with commenting on close.

Comment: @Alexis Why `/usr/local/bin`? Why executable permissions? It doesn't look like this file has to be executed directly, or that it needs to be somewhere in `PATH`.

Comment: @muru Feel free to re-edited if you're not in agreement, here is a thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/195652/is-there-a-standard-place-for-placing-custom-linux-scripts, but respect to permissions, i could be wrong, not my strong area, i couldn't find where i get this recommendation, regards

Comment: @Alexis Yep, I'm rolling back. Nothing so far indicates that the script needs to be in `PATH` or that it needs to be executable by the user.

Comment: I used `/usr/local/z` for the installation path and `/usr/local/man/man1` for the man page. Execute permissions and inclusion in `PATH` weren't necessary after sourcing the script in `.bashrc`. Using this method I was able to easily integrate `z` for all users on the machine (shared dev machine). Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

From [here](https://www.vultr.com/docs/boost-productivity-with-z-and-zsh-on-ubuntu)

> - Download `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rupa/z/master/z.sh`.
> - Install `printf "\n\n#initialize Z (https://github.com/rupa/z) \n. ~/z.sh \n\n" >> .bashrc`. This command appends `. ~/z.sh` to your
>     .`bashrc` file, which in turn tells it to run Z upon start-up.
> - Reload shell `source ~/.bashrc`.
>
> To test how Z works, browse to these directories:
>
> ```
> cd /etc/systemd/system
> cd /usr/share/nano
> cd /etc/kernel/postinst.d
> cd ~
> ```
>
> Now, from your terminal, type in `z sys` and push the tab button, then
>   enter. Next, type `z nano` and hit the tab button, then enter again.
>   You will see in both cases that Z automatically knew to `cd` into the
>   first and second directories where we initially browsed.
>
> ### Using Z with Zsh
>
> - Run `printf "\n\n#initialize Z (https://github.com/rupa/z) \n. ~/z.sh \n\n" >> .zshrc`. This command appends `. ~/z.sh` to `.zshrc`
>     file, which tells it to run Z on start-up.
> - Reload shell `source ~/.zshrc`.

### Using Z with Zsh + Oh My Zsh

Just add `z` to the plugins list in `~/.zshrc`

```
plugins=(
 git
 z
)
```

Download the `z` script to your home directory:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rupa/z/master/z.sh -O ~/.z
```

Then:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: @GAD3R is it really necessary to download the z script ? isn't it integrated the oh-my-zsh fw ?

Comment: Without the `z` script you may receive `_z_dirs:2: no such file or directory: /home/$USER/.z` error. To reproduce the problem : `mv .z .z.bak` , then execute some jumps.

Comment: @GAD3R .z is the data directory. All you have to do is `mkdir .z`. Even if you don't, when you receive the error, it creates the directory, after which the error stops appearing unless you remove the folder again. .z is NOT meant to be the script.

Answer (score 1):

When installing scripts like this (shell augmentation), it is usually a good idea to install them to `/etc/profile.d`. To download and install in a single step, you can use the following command:

```
sudo curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rupa/z/master/z.sh \
          -o /etc/profile.d/z.sh
```

Some of the advantages of installing your shell modifications on `/etc/profile.d`:

- It will be available for all shells and users;
- There's no need to `chmod +x`;
- It is easier to uninstall (just remove the file);
- It is easier to remember where you put them.

Comment: this simply did not work

Comment: Worked well on Git Bash for Windows (without sudo of course), thanks!