# How to add /home/username/bin to $PATH?

Tags: home-directory, environment-variables, paths

Show how you can add `/home/<yourusername>/bin` to the `$PATH` variable. Use `$HOME` (or `~`) to
represent your home directory.

Comment: **Reopen Voters** `/home/<yourusername>/bin` is a **Special** directory that gets automatically added to the $PATH after it's been created and `~/.profile` is reloaded. The duplicate target is about adding generic directories to the path such as `/mary/had/a/little/lamb`.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix So what? Why should this be reopened? Do the answers to the dupe no longer apply? In fact, the accepted answer to the dupe mentions this very directory, and provides the same snippet that's in the default `~/.profile`!

Comment: @muru The "so what" is that you don't need to add `/home/YOURNAME/bin` to the`$PATH`. It's done automatically.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix again, does that mean the answers to the dupe can't be used?

Comment: **Reopen Voters**: The only "special" part is that after you create this directory and start a login shell (or source `~/.profile`), this gets added to the `PATH`. For all other cases, the answers to the dupe will have to be used. ***This is a dupe.***

Comment: Yes the dupe handles adding a directory to the path. This question is explicit about `/home/YOURNAME/bin` which means you don't want to add it to the path. This could account for duplicates mentioned in comments by @sdaffa23fdsf like the accepted answer here might cause. I've asked @sdaffa23fdsf for documented examples of multiple instances of `~/bin` in the path. This question could almost be thought of as "What directories do you NOT WANT TO ADD TO THE PATH".

Answer (score 73, accepted):

To do that you need to type in your terminal:

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

This change is only temporary (it works only in the current session of the shell). To make it permanent, add the line to your .bashrc file located in your home directory.

Comment: I would use /home/user_name rather then $HOME

Comment: It is the same. If you try "echo $HOME" you will probably see the folder /home/user_name...

Comment: $HOME is a variable and is thus ambiguous. IMO it is best to use the full path in scripts and when adding to your $PATH

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Your `HOME` is not guaranteed to by at the same location on different systems. For example, I use the same `.bashrc` on Linux and MacOS, and hard-coding the full path would not work.

Answer (score 40):

Ubuntu (and Debian based distros) automatically add `$HOME/bin` to the PATH if that directory is present. You can check this in `~/.profile`:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Comment: In case `~/.profile` is not loaded add this to your `~.bashrc`: `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: What does "-d" do? This actually prepends several ~/bin into $PATH if you have multiple logins.

Comment: @sdaffa23fdsf "-d" is for a directory. To check its existence

Comment: @sdaffa23fdsf Do you have a documented example of the multiple `~/bin`? In that case the `~/.profile` script should be changed to check if `~/bin` is already in the path before prepending it to `$PATH`.

Comment: I actually need to create this file in Arch.

Comment: When exactly does `~/.profile` get sourced? I used to think that sourcing the `~/.bashrc` file with `. ~/.bashrc` also sources the `~/.profile` file, but I just proved to myself that is _not_ the case! Rather, it's the other way around!: sourcing the `~/.profile` file with `. ~/.profile` actually sources the `~/.bashrc` file as well, so long as the default Ubuntu `~/.profile` file is in-use, since it contains lines to do so if running bash.

Comment: Note also that on Linux Ubuntu, a backup copy of your default `~/.profile` file resides in `/etc/skel/.profile`. Other default files are in the `/etc/skel/` directory too.