# How to run scripts without typing the full path?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'd like to know if there is a way to run  program/shell script without typing full path:

```
/opt/idea/bin/idea.sh
```

Comment: You can always give the full path of the file.

Comment: Thank you @muru, this I know, but it is a program I use often, so I would like to be able to run it with a simple command, not a long file path.

Comment: http://nufailm.blogspot.com/2012/05/custom-launcher-for-intellij-idea-in.html this will help for idea :)

Answer (score 81):

You can just create [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). Create it in `/usr/local/bin`. All you need is to run command:

```
sudo ln -s /full/path/to/your/file /usr/local/bin/name_of_new_command
```

After that you should make your `file` executable:

```
chmod +x /full/path/to/your/file
```

Now you should be able to run `name_of_new_command` at any time in your terminal.

Note that this is good solution only for home usage of Linux.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't place a symlink in `/usr/local/bin` that points to a script in a private home folder, such as `/home/jack/myscript.sh`, as only user `jack` would usually be able to execute it. The symlink will be visible for other users, but not the file it points to. On a single-user system this may not matter, but still, it is "good practice" to place scripts (or links to scripts) that *all* users can read in `/usr/local/bin`, and private, self-made scripts (or links to scripts) of a single user in their `~/bin` folder.

Comment: add a symlink in /usr/sbin/ makes it accessible from anywhere

Answer (score 33):

You can add `/opt/idea/bin` to your `PATH` variable:

```
PATH=/opt/idea/bin:"$PATH"
```

After this you can run it with simply `idea.sh`.

You probably want to add this line in your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: also: if you make the script executable, the .sh extension can be left away (assuming you use the shebang at the top of the script). simply "idea" is enough then.

Comment: @Jacob: you cannot leave off the extension, as that is part of the executable's file name (this isn't Windows, where magic like that causes other issues).  In order to call the script with the name `idea`, you would have to create a link or alias with that name pointing at the `idea.sh` script.

Comment: @JonathanCallen Callen you certainly can! make the script executable, remove the .sh extension from both the filename and the command to run it, given the fact that you start the script with the shebang #!/bin/bash.

Comment: @Jacob what I mean is *without renaming the file*, you cannot (and it appears this is part of a larger software package, so you *shouldn't* just rename files)

Comment: @JonathanCallen Hi Jonathan, I cannot see the context of this script, but in general, if it is a "main" file, or a script to call another main application file (which it is I guess, otherwise there would be no reason to call it from the user interface) it is concidered bad practice to use the language extension.

Comment: @Jacob can you please include a link to this "bad practice"? I think that's plain wrong.

Comment: @janos look at the lintian rules for debian installer packages: http://lintian.debian.org/tags/script-with-language-extension.html

Comment: Thanks @Jacob, notice it says *"When scripts are installed into a directory in the system PATH"*. The `idea.sh` script is not such script, in fact moving it outside its installation dir is completely unsupported. The Debian packaging rules don't apply here.

Comment: Hi Janos, my turn to thank you :), but I believe the arguments, mentioned in the text are the same in this situation, but I am afraid we will be accused of being off topic soon. Let everyone do what they think is best.

Answer (score 17):

You can create a function in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
some-name () {
    /path/to/your/file
    # or:
    #cd /path/to/your
    #./path
}
```

---

Or you can create an `alias`:

```
alias some-name='/path/to/your/file'
# or  
#alias some-name='cd /path/to/your/; ./file'
```

In both cases, you can run it by calling:

```
$ some-name
```

---

If the file doesn't depend on where it's running, consider adding it to your `~/bin`:

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
cp /path/to/you/file ~/bin
# or mv /path/to/you/file ~/bin
# or ln -s /path/to/you/file ~/bin
```

`~/bin`, if it exists, gets added to your `$PATH` automatically. Then you directly call `file`:

```
$ file
```

(Bad choice of name though, consider calling it something less generic.)

Comment: @Oli always give my the five minutes, I tend to add indents. :) It's just annoying as I need to trick the editor to use Ctrl-K for second-level indents.

Comment: +1 in particular for the solution of adding `file` to your `~/bin`, which is what I usually do (for longer scripts). I'd have probably even put that one at the top :) Aliases are good for shortcuts to commands with certain parameters, e.g., `alias l='ls -CF'`. [Though I have seen much more awesome uses of aliases](http://simpletondigest.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/building-a-better-macro/). I don't tend to declare functions in `~/.bashrc` (I prefer to have all my scripts organised in separate files in `~/bin`). Though all this is a matter of taste, I guess :)

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa I just gave preference to the methods that most easily lend themselves to `cd`, because the script may depend on the working directory. :) Otherwise, yes, I tend to put files in `~/bin` myself.

Answer (score 10):

You can create a launcher by using following command:

`gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new <path-where-to-save>`.
I t will open this window.

[image]

Name it whatever you like and in command box type following

`sh -c '/opt/idea/bin/idea.sh'` and save it.

Now you can run that file using newly created launcher

OR

You can create a .desktop file with following contents

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=<whatever-you-want>
Exec=sh -c '/opt/idea/bin/idea.sh'     
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon='<path to an icon file if you want>'
```

Now save it with `.desktop` extension on any place.

Make it executable with this command `chmod a+x  <your-desktop-file>`

Now double click to open it.

Answer (score 7):

We can also run `/opt/idea/bin/idea.sh` file directly using `bash_aliases`

Open `~/.bashrc` file by running,

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Remove the `#` before the lines and save it, so that the lines will look like,

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Now open `~/.bash_aliases` file,

```
gedit ~/.bash_aliases
```

Add the below lines in that file and save it,

```
alias idea='cd /opt/idea/bin && sudo ./idea.sh'
```

Finally source the `~/.bashrc` file,

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now you can run `/opt/idea/bin/idea.sh` file directly by,

```
idea
```

Answer (score 7):

We can define a function and a add hotkey by using [`bind`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/bind.1.php) command to call that. Open `~/.bashrc` file and add these line to it:

```
# define function that opens your program in working directory
Openprog(){
    /your-Program/path/here
}

# bind hotkey to it (<F12>)
bind -x '"\e[24~":"Openprog"'
```

Now when you press <kbd>F12</kbd>, your program will launch.

**Note:**
A quick way to determine the escape code:

Open your terminal and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Now press your favorite keyboard shortcut. The correct escape code should appear. Just make sure to replace `^[` with `\e` before adding the shortcut to, e.g. replace `^[[24~` with `\e[24~`.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other good answers, consider symlinking into `~/.local/bin` and adding this directory to your PATH (from within your `.bashrc` for instance).  This method does not require special permissions (unlike symlinking to `/usr/local/bin`, for instance).  This way, you may have a standard directory struction without flooding your $HOME.  Read more about this on these https://unix.stackexchange.com/ questions:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11544/what-is-the-difference-between-opt-and-usr-local
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36871/where-should-a-local-executable-be-placed

Answer (score 1):

Create a soft link of it in `/usr/bin` direcotyr:

```
ln -s /opt/idea/bin/idea.sh /usr/bin/idea.sh
```

Now run it using:

```
idea.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply use

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

and add

```
PATH=/full/path/to/file:"$PATH"
```

at the end of it, then save and exit. Afterwards, you can simply type the file name.

Answer (score 0):

> I followed all the answers here and other places and so few fail to mention that you may need to **LOG OUT** for the command to eventually work.

Just to recap, especially for **Xubuntu**, but for other **Debian/Ubuntu** variants as well I wrote these simple instructions.

(in the following instructions we use directory **~/bin**, because that's automatically a place from where these OSs look for commands. See **[here](https://askubuntu.com/a/402410/258952)**:

## Fool-proof instructions to get your command to work:

```
# Open Terminal with Ctrl + Alt + T (or your system's own shortcut)

# You'll work in your home folder, no need to use sudo for any of this

cd # Go to home directory

mkdir -p bin # Create folder ~/bin if it doesn't exist

# Be careful not to type /bin, that's the bin folder in system root: /

sudo apt install nano # Skip this if you have Nano installed

nano bin/yournewcommand

    # In Nano, type:

    printf "Your new command works! \n" # \n means line break

    # Ctrl+X To leave Nano

    # Ctrl+Y To save the unsaved file

    # Enter to confirm

chmod +x bin/yournewcommand

yournewcommand # If you just created the bin folder, this command might not yet work.

# You must now log out and log back in to make the bin folder noticed (I think)

yournewcommand # Now it works! (You can use Tab to autocomplete the command you're typing)

# If you add a second file/command, it should work without logging out (at least in my tests)
```