# Execute command with relative (upper) path. Using another working directory

Tags: command-line, scripts

I need to run an application (msp430-gcc) using a relative path from a makefile. The issue is that the application is in a different folder branch so I need to do something like this:

```
../../../../tools/msp430/bin/msp430-gcc
```

Here the problem is that the system is unable to find the application. However, if I do:

```
cd ../../../../tools/msp430/bin
./msp430-gcc
```

then it works.

Do you know how I could run the application from my initial location without using "cd"?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Also look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/427818/how-can-i-run-this-sh-script-without-typing-the-full-path/527008#527008), may be this is what really want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keywords here is: **running command with different working directory**. You can google it yourself to find more information.

You can call it using parentheses - `()`

```
$ (cd ../../../../tools/msp430/bin &&./msp430-gcc)
```

Parentheses will create a new subshell to execute commands inside it. This new subshell will change directory and execute program in this directory.

Quote from `man bash`

```
(list)    list  is  executed  in  a  subshell  environment (see COMMAND
          EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT below).  Variable assignments and builtin 
          commands that affect the shell's environment do not remain in 
          effect after the command completes.  The return status is the
          exit status of list.
```

where a `list` is just a normal sequence of commands.

```
Variables in a subshell are not visible outside the block of code in the subshell.
They are not accessible to the parent process, to the shell that launched the
subshell. These are, in effect, local variables. 
Directory changes made in a subshell do not carry over to the parent shell.
```

In conclusion: subshell will see all variables from `parent shell`, but it will use them as **local**. Changes made by subshell to variables not affect `parent shell`

---

Another method using `sh`:

```
$ sh -c 'cd ../../../../tools/msp430/bin; ./msp430-gcc'
```

In this case `sh -c` will not spawn **subshell**, but create own new shell. That's why it cannot see `parent shell` **variables**. So remember: if you set some variable before executing `sh -c` new shell will not see it.

But there is also a little confuse between using **single quotes** `''` and **double quotes** `""` in `sh -c`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) question to understand difference, I will only show little example:

```
$ TEST=test1
$ sh -c 'echo $TEST'

$ sh -c 'TEST=test2;echo $TEST'
test2
```

after executing first command nothing was printed out. It's because new shell do not have `TEST` variable, and `''` do not expand `$TEST`.

```
$ sh -c "echo $TEST"
test1
$ sh -c "TEST=test2;echo $TEST"
test1
```

here first command `$TEST` was expanded because of using `""`, and even if we set `TEST` variable in new shell `$TEST` already expanded, and it printed out **test1**

---

### Sources

1. About [`sh -c "command"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951346/is-there-a-subshell-created-when-i-run-sh-c-command-a-new-shell-or-none-of). Very full answer.
2. About [parentheses](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26063/how-are-parenthesis-interpreted-at-the-command-line)
3. Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786376/how-do-i-run-a-program-with-a-different-working-directory-from-current-from-lin)
4. From bash guide [about parentheses](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/subshells.html)
5. [Difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) between `''` and `""`