# Run program from anywhere without changing directory

Tags: command-line, alias

I wish to create an alias, which runs program x, without changing the current directory I am in. What I have now is:

```
alias x = "cd /home/path_to_x && ./x"
```

This works, but changes my directory. What I wish to do is something like:

```
alias x="./home/path_to_x/x
```

But then I get no such file or directory. Anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: set an alias like `alias x='/home/path_to_x/x'`. Don't use `.` before `/home`. `.`(dot) refers to current directory.

Comment: Does `x` really need to be run while being in `/home/path_to_x`? Or are you just unsure about how to run a program residing in a specific directory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute command with relative (upper) path. Using another working directory](http://askubuntu.com/questions/527156/execute-command-with-relative-upper-path-using-another-working-directory)

Comment: One more similar question http://askubuntu.com/questions/427818/how-can-i-run-this-sh-script-without-typing-the-full-path

Answer (score 14, accepted):

DON'T CD, just run it using its *absolute path*

This version:

```
cd /home/path_to_x && ./x
```

changes directory to an absolute path (you see how `/home/...` starts at the root directory) and then runs the executable at the *relative* path `./x` (that is, relative to the new working directory).

This version:

```
./home/path_to_x/x
```

tries to run the executable at the *relative* path `./home/path_to_x/x`, which means relative to *whatever your current working directory is now*. That explains why you get the error - this relative path really doesn't exist.

The command you want would be:

```
/home/path_to_x/x
```

using the absolute path (starting at the root directory `/`) again.

Oh, and you can also just add `/home/path_to_x` to your `PATH` instead of creating the alias. See: [How to run scripts without typing the full path?](https://askubuntu.com/q/427818/760903)

Comment: This is the correct answer for the question as posed.

Comment: This would only be incorrect if the program needed to be run in a specific directory that it gets from `pwd`

Comment: @Whaaaaaat is right. `/home/path_to_x/x` is not functionally equivalent to `(cd /home/path_to_x && ./x)`; if it works or not is application dependent.

Comment: Although you're right in general, for this specific question OP was visibly trying to run from the absolute path (just with a one-character mistake). However, I'm sure they can clarify if working directory is important in this case.

Answer (score 8):

If you do not want the `cd` to stick after the alias substitution, use a subshell with `(` y `)`:

```
alias my_x="(cd /home/path_to_x && ./x)&"
```

you can check it with

```
alias test_y="(cd /tmp && sleep 10 ) & "
```

Note that [the solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/537456/16395)

```
alias my_y="/home/path_to_x/x"
```

is not exactly equivalent. In fact, if called via `my_x`, the `x` program is run with a current directory `/home/path_to_x/`, while if called by `my_y`, `x` is run with a current directory which is the one where the command `my_y` was issued. This can be important or not depending on what `x` is doing.

About the [OP solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/537300/16395), it works in `bash`:

```
romano@RRyS:~$ pwd
/home/romano
romano@RRyS:~$ alias x="cd /bin && ./echo A >/dev/null  &"
romano@RRyS:~$ x
[1] 16611
romano@RRyS:~$ pwd
/home/romano
```

but not in `zsh`:

```
[romano:~] % pwd
/home/romano
[romano:~] % alias x="cd /bin && ./echo A >/dev/null &"
[romano:~] % x
[1] 16744
[1]  + 16744 done       ./echo A > /dev/null                                    
1& [romano:/bin] % pwd
/bin
[romano:/bin] %
```

It seems that  [bash and zsh execute lists in different ways](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162286/difference-of-behavior-in-bash-and-zsh) ...so it's better to add the explicit parenthesis... thanks @EliahKagan  for pointing it to me.

Comment: Giving the trailing `&` higher precedence than `&&` seems like it may be unique to `zsh`. I tried `sleep 5 && echo done &` in `zsh`, `bash`, `ksh`, `mksh`, `dash`, and even one non-Bourne-style shell (`tcsh`). Only `zsh` evaluated `sleep 5` in the foreground; all the others returned immediately (then also printed `done` five seconds later, of course). On the other hand, even if this is entirely a peculiarity of `zsh`, I think adding explicit `( )` (or `{ ;}`) is reasonable, as it conveys the intent to other humans (or to oneself, when reading the script or history later).

Answer (score 4):

If the file which you want to run is already executeable, why don't you add it to you PATH variable?

If your executable file is `/home/user/aplication/appX` just enter

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/user/application
```

to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`

After restarting your console, you can run it simply with `appX`

I think this is the most clean solution.

Answer (score 3):

Putting a `&` at the end seems to do the trick:

```
alias x = "cd /home/path_to_x && ./x &"
```

Comment: Are you sure? After executing `x` you are in `/home/path_to_x`. The `&` at the end simply send the process in background.

Comment: @Rmano This actually works. `cd`s in background jobs don't affect the caller (which makes sense--it'd be really weird if they did). This is because [asynchronous execution uses a subshell](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Execution-Environment). Though this would be better if it explained why it works and what `&` does--and how running in the background is sometimes undesirable--this is (already) a correct answer. ([Explicitly making a subshell with `( )` syntax, as you suggest](http://askubuntu.com/a/537308), is probably a better solution most of the time though.)

Comment: @EliahKagan you are right. I checked the solution with `zsh` and effectively it works in `bash` and not in `zsh`... must be some difference in how the aliases are expanded.

Comment: Asked a question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162286/difference-of-behavior-in-bash-and-zsh

Comment: @Rmano did you enable the settings related to `pushd` in `zsh` (I have `setopt autopushd pushdsilent pushdtohome`, and it remembers my cwd.)

Comment: @muru `getopt autopushd pushdsilent pushdtohome` says `-- pushdsilent pushdtohome` (I think it's the default)

Answer (score 0):

Get Backup of your current pwd and and after running your command, undo your last pwd.

```
alias x='dwp=$(pwd) && cd /home/path_to_x && ./x && cd $dwp'
```

Comment: You misunderstood the effect of that Rmano's alias. The command line is not blocked. It's just that the output of the alias (`test`) pushed the cursor to the next line. You can still do whatever you want there (including pressing enter to open a fresh new prompt).

Comment: yup, yes correct. @mure :|

Comment: Note that since you use double quotes the variable will include the current directory *at the time the alias is defined*. Use single quotes to defer evaluation until the alias is expanded. However, `pushd` and `popd` do what your answer does. `alias x='pushd /home/path_to_x && ./x && popd'`