# How to open bash files with terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am new to Ubuntu and I just started learning bash.
How can I open bash files through terminal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### To edit:

Use any editor you like:

```
gedit some_file.sh
nano  some_file.sh
vim   some_file.sh
# ...
```

#### To run:

Either make it executable and run it giving the path:

```
chmod +x some_file.sh
./some_file.sh
```

Or tell `bash` to run it:

```
bash some_file.sh
```

Also see: [How to run scripts without typing the full path?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427818/how-can-i-run-this-sh-script-without-typing-the-full-path)

Answer (score 2):

Give it permission to run

```
chmod +x /path/to/yourscript.sh
```

And run your script:

```
/path/to/yourscript.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Make it executable using

```
chmod +x filename
```

and run it in terminal using

```
./filename
```

Or

You simply

```
bash filename
```

Answer (score 2):

To open a bash file for editing (something with an .sh suffix) you can use a text editor like nano.

`nano filename.sh`

If you want to run a bash script you can do it in several ways.

`./filename.sh`

or

`sh filename.sh`

Best, 
Lev