# Why do I have to change into my private bin folder to execute an .sh script?

Tags: scripts, sh

I have a private bin folder in my home directory. It's is also in my path. If I try to run a script from anywhere else in my system but within that folder, I get

```
  sh: 0: Can't open [name of script].sh
```

If I execute something like `sh ~/bin/killwine.sh` it works

I would like to be able to execute the script from anywhere without changing my location.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably forgot to make it executable, if you did, the `sh <scriptname>` would be:  `<scriptname>`

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/427818/how-can-i-run-this-sh-script-without-typing-the-full-path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you type `sh somescript.sh`, the system looks for `sh` in the path not `somescript.sh`.

Then the system finds `sh` and passes the argument `somescript.sh` to it. Then `sh` looks for `somescript.sh` in the current folder or in the specified folder `~/bin/` if you typed

```
sh ~/bin/somescirpt.sh.
```

To make the system look for `somescript.sh` in the path use it directly as a command, without the sh prefix. In other words, type in the terminal:

```
somescript.sh
```

For that to work, `somescript.sh` needs located in a folder in the path, in this case `~/bin/` and it needs to be executable, as others have pointed out. I include the command below for completeness.

```
chmod +x ~/bin/somescript.sh
```

Also see [How do I run .sh files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-files-in-terminal) and

[How to run scripts without typing the full path?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427818/how-can-i-run-this-sh-script-without-typing-the-full-path)

Hope this helps

Comment: Ya know, I've been using Ubuntu and variants as desktop (and sometime server) user for 5 years and this was never clear to me... (and of course I only have learned to use it via school of hard knocks). Thank you...it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

As the comment said, your script may not be marked for execution. When you call it trough sh what you're doing is telling the shell to read its content and execute the functions inside the text file, is not the same as calling an executable directly. Try this:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/killwine.sh
```

Then, try to execute it again from another directory. Also, make sure the first line on the script contains this, so the system knows that it has to be executed by a shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Comment: If he's running it on the command line with `sh script` then he probably wants `#!/bin/sh` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As darent and user68186 explained the script may not have the executable bit set. If the bit is set you can run the script if you're in the directory the script is in simply by prefixing it with **./**. For example:

> ./myscript.sh

You don't have to have the .sh at the end of the filename either, but it's good form to append the .sh to let others know it's a shell script.