# How to run two 'python manage.py runserver' commands of two different folder in a single terminal

Tags: command-line, python, application-development

I have two different python project placed in different folder (project 1 in `pydir1` directory, project 2 in `pydir2` directory).

Every time, I need to open two new terminal and run the `python manage.py runserver` command after change to the project directory.

Open 1st terminal window and

```
cd pydir1
python manage.py runserver 8000
```

and then open 2nd terminal windows and

```
cd pydir2
python manage.py runserver 8001
```

Is there a easier way to do it, at the same time able to see the log progress in the terminal windows?

Comment: You can do it, but how will you make sense of the combined log output?

Comment: @muru I was looking at a command that will open two terminal windows and run it separately instead of manually open two terminal windows. However, I am open to any solution that can help me make it easier to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single GNOME Terminal command:

```
gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=Default --working-directory pydir1 \ 
  -e 'python manage.py runserver 8000' --tab-with-profile=Default \ 
  --working-directory pydir2 -e 'python manage.py runserver 8001'
```

- The `--tab-with-profile` options open new tabs. (If you prefer windows to tabs, replace `tab` with `window` in the command.)
- `--working-directory` saves you `cd`.
- `-e` defines the command to be run in that tab. You can use custom profiles instead, and skip the `-e ...` part.

Save it as an [`alias`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427818/how-can-i-run-this-sh-script-without-typing-the-full-path/527005#527005), or create [a custom launcher](https://askubuntu.com/a/64222/158442) to simplify running this long command.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend you to use [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) which is part of the package [inotify-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/inotify-tools). After installing this package you can automatically restart your server whenever you saved a changed to your working directory. For example with the following script you can restart the server whenever you modify a source file:

```
while inotifywait -r -e modify pydir1; do
    # ...bash code to restart the server...
done
```