# set shortcut for executable program from terminal

Tags: command-line, eclipse, shortcuts, symbolic-link

I installed a program and I want to create a shortcut.

e.g. I want to type `eclipse` into the terminal to launch the program.

I already copied the eclipse folder in `/home/user/Programs` and created a symbolinc link to the executable `/home/user/Programs/eclipse/eclipse` (the one that allows me to launch the program by typing `./eclipse`, I guess it is a binary or like a shell script) in a folder located in `/home/bin` and I added this last folder to the path using export.

But I have this issue:

```
bash: ./eclipse: No such file or directory
```

Can you please help me on that? I am sure that I missed something

Comment: You may want to check the current path with `echo $PATH`. Also, what's /home/bin?

Comment: AFAIK only binaries that are in your `$PATH` folders are readily executed by typing them into the terminal; but binaries in  subfolders cannot be executed. Check your `echo $PATH`  and compare that with `which eclipse` commands. If your eclipse binary is in a subfolder, say `/usr/bin/eclipse` you will need to add `/usr/bin/eclipse` to your `$PATH` as well. Let me know if this helps

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I run this sh script without typing the full path?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/427818/how-can-i-run-this-sh-script-without-typing-the-full-path)

Answer (score 4):

You can use alias also. Add below line to the `~/.bashrc` file.(`gedit ~/.bashrc` command will open file for the editing.) Then close and open a terminal.

`alias eclipse='/home/<user>/Programs/eclipse/eclipse'`

Then type `eclipse` to open Eclipse. You don't need `./` at the begining of the command.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo ln -s /home/<user>/Programs/eclipse/eclipse /usr/bin/eclipse
```

Preplace `<user>` with your username