# Ubuntu execute file without ./

Tags: 15.10, tcl, shebang

Using a shebang line, I added the functionality to launch a TCL script using the wish shell. However, I can only quickly launch the file by typing `./filename.tcl` in the terminal. I would like to know, is there a way to run the same script without typing the `./` before the filename?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run this sh script without typing the full path?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/427818/how-can-i-run-this-sh-script-without-typing-the-full-path)

Comment: `./` is the file's path. Writing NOT in all caps doesn't change that.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't know that. I'll edit it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you leave out the path to the file then your shell is going to look for the command via the $PATH variable. The "." is the current directory, which provides a path to the file. Your options are:

Put the file inside a subdirectory like bin:

```
$ bin/filename.tcl
```

This is most likely not what you want. What you might want is to alter your $PATH to include the current directory.

```
$ PATH=$PATH:. filename.tcl
```

It's most likely not wise to export the current directory to the $PATH variable as it may cause some unexpected behavior. It may be better to export the full path to your bin directory. So for example if you were working at $HOME/my/code/bin/filename.tcl then you could add this to your .bashrc (or whatever shell config file you use)

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/my/code/bin"
```

Then you should be able to run

```
filename.tcl
```

Without specifying the path to the directory.