# How to run a script from terminal

Tags: command-line, scripts, python

Hi I would like to run a script from the terminal, is there anyway to do that?
For example : if I have a python script I would normally run it with this command :

```
python script.py
```

How can I run this script just by typing in the filename of the script in the terminal (even if i'm in another directory) ?

**Another answer I found pretty helpful : 
[How to run scripts without typing the full path?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427818/how-can-i-run-this-sh-script-without-typing-the-full-path)**

You can just create symlink. Create it in /usr/local/bin. All you need is to run command:

```
sudo ln -s /full/path/to/your/file /usr/local/bin/name_of_new_command
```

After that you should make your file executable:

```
chmod +x /full/path/to/your/file
```

Now you should be able to run name_of_new_command at any time in your terminal.

Note that this is good solution only for home usage of Linux.

Comment: shebang shebang shebang ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way to do this is to place your script in `$HOME/bin` and making sure that the permissions are set to executable:

```
chmod +x  $HOME/bin/script.py
```

Now you should be able to run the script from any directory....

A couple of other points to be aware of:

1. Ensure that `$HOME/bin` is in your `$PATH`, for Ubuntu this will be set by default in `$HOME/.profile` but it does not hurt to check.
2. Ensure that your Python script has the appropriate 'shebang' set:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   ```

Comment: Besides of using chmod and including the script in a location in your path, you should also make sure that your script starts with a shebang, as told in the comments to the OP.

Comment: Also , personal bin folder must be included into the PATH variable, which can be done by uncommenting appropriate line in ~/.profile

Comment: OK I have added in the suggestions, feel free to trim these as you wish :)

Answer (score 4):

Put this line in your `.bashrc` assuming you're using bash as shell:

```
export PATH=/path/to/your/script/:"$PATH"
```

You can use vi, nano or gedit to edit this line in the end of the file. Make sure your script is set to executable mode, if it's a bash script:

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

Or if it's a Python script:

```
chmod +x script.py
```

On your script indicate their type in the first line. If it's Python:

```
#!/bin/python
```

If it's bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
```