# How to install a simle python script

Tags: python3

How do I 'install' a python  script so I can run it when ever I want?

My script looks like:

```
#/usr/bin/env python
import os;

while True:
    comm = input();
    os.system(comm);
```

But when i try to run it I get:

```
/usr/bin/doors.py line2: command not found 
...
```

How to I fix this?

Comment: What's the output of `stat /usr/bin/doors.py` ?   You may have not set executable permissions for it

Comment: Also, what i see is that you're trying to run a command via `os.system()` . It's depreciated. Use `subprocess.popen`

Comment: Also, no need for `;` at the end of each line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run this sh script without typing the full path?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/427818/how-can-i-run-this-sh-script-without-typing-the-full-path)

Comment: Also, you asked "How do I 'install' a python script so I can run it when ever I want?" , what exactly do you mean by that ?

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo in shebang line, which specifies interpreter to use. It should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

which will default to python2.7. Since you've tagged your question python3, you may want to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

You should use the `#!/usr/bin/env python3` line .

As it stands now, your shell is interpreting the script with shebang being treated as a comment as it starts with `#`. Thus, there's no interpreter specified, and by default script will be executed with your current shell. The shell has no idea of what `import` is , hence the command not found error is being shown by the shell.

As a side note, for running native shell commands in `python`, use the `subprocess` module instead of unsecured and deprecated `os.system` function.

Also why are you running user input blindly without any sanity checking?

Comment: That should be `/usr/bin/env`, not `/use/bin/env`

Comment: @trvrm Haha..a typo in my answer too..fixed.. Thanks

Comment: OP has tagged the question `python3`. You might wanna mention that as well, because `#!/usr/bin/env python` is 2.7 by default

Comment: @Serg Edited...

Comment: @heemayl do you mind if I edit it a bit ?

Comment: @Serg NP..go ahead :)

Comment: Edit made, let me know what you think

Comment: @Serg Thanks, good one..I have added one last line :)

Comment: @Serg until PEP8 changes, `/usr/bin/python` will be Python 2, not Python 3, even if Python 3 is the only available Python. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/3