# git clone hex2hcd "command not found" Ubuntu bluetooth

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, git

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and my bluetooth stopped working.  The accepted solution for this problem is to find the driver in hex format and convert it to hcd for installation:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone git://github.com/jessesung/hex2hcd.git
cd hex2hcd
make
./hex2hcd ../BCMxxxx.xxx.xxx.xx.hex BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd (Correct hex file and required hcd name here)
```

So I followed the commands and installed git and everything seems to go just fine until the end when I get a "command not found":

```
$ git clone git://github.com/jessesung/hex2hcd.git
Cloning into 'hex2hcd'...
remote: Counting objects: 8, done.
remote: Total 8 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 8
Receiving objects: 100% (8/8), 8.71 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
~$ cd hex2hcd
:~/hex2hcd$ make
gcc -O2 -march=native    hex2hcd.c   -o hex2hcd
~/hex2hcd$ hex2hcd BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0084.0086.hex BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd
hex2hcd: command not found
```

Why am I getting "command not found" ???

If i look in the directory the command hex2hcd is present:

```
~/hex2hcd$ ls
BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0084.0086.hex  hex2hcd  hex2hcd.c  LICENSE  Makefile
```

And if I examine the hex2hcd file its properties are executable.

I do not know what to do next to resolve this.

hmm.  This question has been marked as a duplicate to:

[How to run scripts without typing the full path?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427818/how-to-run-scripts-without-typing-the-full-path)

But I do not understand how that helps or how I would have ever found that page.  Actually another suggest to prepend ./ before my command is a helpful answer as it has solved the problem.  But that solution is not found on the page marked as duplicate.

I don't understand why I need to prepend ./ when I am already in the directory with the command ...  So I have a solution but do not understand why it is needed.

Comment: How about trying `./hex2hcd BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0084.0086.hex BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd`, i.e., add `./` in front?

Comment: You should reply to our comments too in addition to editing the question, otherwise I wouldn't have known you tried what I said. In any case, a bare `hexhcd` does not work because it is not in your `PATH`. Appending `./` works because `.` is an alias for the current directory, so `./hexhcd` is one way of specifying the path to `hexhcd`. The duplicate target that @muru posted provides ways to modify `PATH` by creating symlinks or editing `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-to-execute-a-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the folder where that file is is not in `PATH` variable, and by default any command you just type into the prompt will be searched from the list of dirs in the PATH. You can type in `git` and run it just like that because it's located in some directory that is listed in `PATH` and yours is not.

Use `·/command` , give full path like `/home/admin/somedir/command` , or add that dir to your `PATH` variable. Alternative is also to make an alias to the full path.

In your case the last command should be

```
./hex2hcd BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0084.0086.hex BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd
```

Comment: If this answer has answered your question, please consider leaving an upvote and/or marking this answer as accepted