# how to add .sh file or path to .profile to run my app?

Tags: command-line, scripts, bashrc, .profile

In home I have a project folder `nomse/bin/main.dart`. in terminal. If I use command like,

```
dart nomse/bin/main.dart
```

I can run my app.

**UPDATE-1:**
I need to add path to `.profile` so I can run my app without typing a path on terminal. (I know how to add path to .profile), just bear with me.

All I need is that (as an example because I don't know how to do it) I need to add the nomse/bin/main.dart in .profile and run like dart nomse.

I need to give a name to my path like nomse. So I can run like dart nomse.
How do I do that?

**UPDATE-2:**

```
in .profile I add path as 
PATH="$HOME/.nomse/bin/main.dart:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

how can I give a name to my path so I can run on terminal like?

```
dart nomse
```

Comment: thanks Afshin, my problem is I am new to .profile and .sh, I need to run my main.dart with a command like dart main.dart. So if I add path to .profile how the dart command will knows main.dart? should I give name, like typing a dart nomse?

Comment: OK, then your question is duplicated of https://askubuntu.com/q/427818/283843

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear from your post, whether you want to add PATH to the executable `dart` or to the parameter `main.dart`.

For the first one, just export the PATH.

For the later, do you want to execute like: `dart`**`paramter`** should get expanded to `dart $HOME/.`**`paramter`**`/bin/main.dart`? 
In that case you can write a small macro/function in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
function mydart()
{
   nomse="$1"
   /path/to/dart "$HOME/.$nomse/bin/main.dart
}
```

Then on terminal call `mydart nomse`.

Comment: thanks Mike, I am new to scripts, path, .profile etc. I am guessing your answer will be close what I am looking for. In my update 2 I have main.dart file. Normaly in terminal to run the file I have to use dart /and/my/path/main.dart. Now I add my path into .profile. I need a name my path so I can run just typing dart nomse in terminal. ".nomse" is a folder in my Home. and inside I have another folder call bin and inside that I have a main.dart file. Where I should add the variable name? Is my .profile path is ok. If so, should I add the function to .bashrc as you wrote?

Comment: the /path/to/dart already in my path. so I try to use dart "$HOME/.$nomse/bin/main.dart and fail ??

Comment: @Nick, what do you mean by `dart "$HOME/.$nomse/bin/main.dart` fails? DO you get command not found error? In any case, the variable `$nomse` is a local var to the function `mydart`. You have to add this function to `~/.bashrc`. Please read the answer carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your command `dart` lies in a folder `/path/to/folder/containing/dart/command`, then just add the following line to the bottom of your `~/.profile`:

```
dir=/path/to/folder/containing/dart/command
if [ -d "$dir" ] ; then
  PATH="$PATH:$dir"
fi
```

In addition to this (or alternatively) you can add the following line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/folder/containing/dart/command"
```

For your current session, you can run this command.

This will tell the system where the executable `dart` lies.Now you can call

```
dart /path/to/main.dart
```

from anywhere.

Comment: thanks, but my problem is I don't want to use the path. If I add path to .profile like update the my question, I need to run on terminal like dart nomse, and it will run my app. my problem is I don't know how to give a name to my path in .profile