# How do I make a shell program run with the script name? and script help

Tags: bash, scripts

Very new to ubuntu here, and I have been assigned to create the prarg bash shell script below. Please bear with me I am trying to be very clear by providing all relevant examples.

ASSIGNMENT:
1.  Modify the prargs program to precede each argument by its number. Thus, typing `prargs a 'b c' d` should give the following output:

```
1: a  
2: b c  
3: d
```

The issue I'm having is the book example runs the following script by typing in "prargs a b c". When I type this I get the error: `prargs:command not found`. How do I get the script to run this way? The only way I can run the script is with  `./prargs.sh` or `bash prargs.sh`.

Script contents:

```
while [ "$#" -ne 0 ]  
do  
    echo "$1"  
    shift
done
```

Because I can't run it as directed, I am stuck. The directions and the book were very unclear, I can find snippets online but the main issue here is syntax for the entire code and I can't find that.

Help?  and Thank you!

Comment: [How to run scripts without typing the full path?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427818/how-to-run-scripts-without-typing-the-full-path)

Comment: it works for me exactly as you wrote it. I did `bash prargs.sh a b c` in the same directory as the file. Note that you wrote `pargs` , which i assume was a typo. Once I set it to executable, `./prargs.sh a b c` also worked.

Comment: @DougSmythies given the assignment output the parameter list should be `a 'b c' d` not `a b c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is the script has the wrong name of `prargs.sh` when the filename should be `prargs`. The second problem is there should be a "shebang" at the top telling the system it is a bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while [ "$#" -ne 0 ]  
do
    ((Count++))
    echo "$Count: $1"  
    shift
done
```

**Note:** Your script was missing the `1:`, `2:`, etc. parameter count. I've added that missing pieces with:

```bash
((Count++))
echo "$Count: $1"
```

So when you run the script you now see:

```bash
$ prargs a 'b c' d
1: a
2: b c
3: d
```

The next problem is calling the `prargs` without specifying a location in front. If you place your script in one of your paths it will be found without specifying a directory. To see your current paths use: `echo $PATH`. Many people will create a path in their home directory for personal scripts:

```bash
mkdir -p $HOME/bin
```

After this reopen the terminal to have it in your path. So create your script as `$HOME/bin/prargs` and then mark it executable:

```bash
chmod a+x $HOME/bin/prargs
```

After this no matter what your current directory is you can type `prargs a 'b c' d`.

Comment: thank you!  You resolved EVERY issue, except I followed your script exactly and it still does not print with the numbers 1, 2, and 3.  Help?

Comment: @queenv After initially posting the script I changed it an hour later to print the numbers. Do you have `((Count++))` line added to your script? Also after it works **perfectly** please click the grey check mark next to the answer so other people know it works.

Comment: ah!  yes it is flawless now!  thank you SO MUCH!!! Also I did not know about the checkmark so thanks for that also :)

Answer (score 1):

For this is necessary to have the script in a predefined path where the shell can find it.

By example, is possible create a new path in the home dir and use it to store scripts by the next steps:

1. Create a folder with the name you want.
2. Open .bashrc in the home directory(for example in the terminal type nano .bashrc).
3. Move to the end of the file and copy paste the next: export PATH="/home/YOUR_USER_NAME/THE_FOLDER_CREATED_FOR_YOUR_SCRIPTS:$PATH"
4. Reboot
   Now when you put something in the folder you created you can run it only with the name

NOTE:
The script to be executed must have execution permission, to give it is as simple as the following command: chmod +x FILE_NAME