# Create a shortcut to a .sh file and put it in /usr/bin

Tags: apt, kali

The two file formats that I encounter when I try to install a software on linux are **.deb** and **.tar.gz** or **.tar.xz**, For the **.deb** I use `apt-get install` and the package will be automatically added to a folder that is in the path variable like `/usr/bin` but for the zipped file formats sometimes I extract it and then the software is in a random place in my file system and I have to navigate to `packageInstalationFolder/bin` to find the **.sh** file in order to launch it. What I want is a way to make a link file to the original **.sh** file and put it in `/usr/bin`. and If you know a better way than this I'll be happy to know it

Comment: The Linux [FHS](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html) would prefer `/usr/local/bin` over `/usr/bin` for this kind of thing. See also [How to run scripts without typing the full path?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427818/how-to-run-scripts-without-typing-the-full-path)

Comment: A tar file opens where you tell it to not a random location.

Comment: @David Yes this is easy to fix, I appologise

Comment: No need. but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple. Create a symbolic link to the executable in `/usr/local/bin`, and you will be able to launch the executable by simply typing the name of the link (that includes the `.sh` extension if you prefer to add that extension to your scripts).

The command to create a symbolic link is `ln -s`, so

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/your/executable.sh /usr/local/bin
```

will create a symbolic link with the name `executable.sh` in `/usr/local/bin` so you can run it simply by typing `executable.sh`.

You can name the link differently:

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/your/executable.sh /usr/local/bin/executable
```

Since no directory `executable` exists, the `ln -s` command will interpret that as the name of the link. Now simply type `executable` to execute that script.

You like to use `/usr/bin`. Don´t. That directory is managed by the packet system of the distribution. Place your manually installed programs (e.g. from `tar.gz` files in `/usr/local/bin`, which serves exactly that purpose. If that directory does not exist, create it first.

Comment: I solved the issue, what I did is that I passed the full path of the original folder, can you edit your solution with ```/full/path/to/your/exe...  ```, may be it can help someone else. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure how the paths I indicated in my answer could be more full than they already are.

Comment: Using a relative path will cause some issues, So maybe It's better to be clear about your instructions.

Comment: Again, where do you see a relative path in my answer?

Comment: It's just to remove ambiguity. the reader can assume that he can use a relative path, it's a common mistake to use a relative path.

Comment: A path that starts with / is an absolute path. There is no ambiguity here. Still, this is rather irrelevant to the problem: relative paths are perfectly fine, and that is actually quite common. You will find many links with relative paths in your system files.