# Where is the system-wide $PATH variable set?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am using Ubuntu Desktop 14.04, and as such, I am using the non-login shell. When I open the GUI terminal, first the non-login shell sessions read the following startup files:

```
/etc/bash.bashrc
~/.bashrc
```

The non-login shells inherit the environment from the parent process, which is a login shell, so the session also reads the following startup files:

```
/etc/profile
~/.bash_profile
```

However, I cannot find the `$PATH` for system-wide paths like `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/sbin`, set in any of these files. Where is the `$PATH` set for these directories?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The (default) system wide `PATH` is set in the `/etc/environment` file.

```
$ cat /etc/environment 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

It is basically the place to save the global environment variables.

Comment: +1, however do you happen to know if `$PATH` it's inherited by the parent login shell or if it's reloaded by each `bash` instance?

Comment: @kos All child processes inherit the environment from parent shell unless of course being run in a modified environment..

Comment: I notice that the shell does not seem to expand the `$HOME` variable. For instance, adding `$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin` to the `PATH` in `/etc/environment` does not enable binaries in this directory to be executed without a path prefix. Using `~/.composer/vendor/bin` does not work either. I'm finding it necessary to add the absolute path, e.g.: `/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/bin`. This seems related (though doesn't explain this behavior): https://askubuntu.com/questions/402353/how-to-add-home-username-bin-to-path

Comment: @BenJohnson That's simply because `/etc/environment` (and `~/.pam/environment`) is read by `pam_env` PAM module, not shell or anything else that understands shell/environment variables; same goes for `~` expansion. So, you need to use absolute path there.