# Update PATH Variable in Byobu for root

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, environment-variables, byobu

I would like to add a directory to the `$PATH` variable for all users, including users who run `byobu` with `sudo byobu`.

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on x86_64.

The desired path is below. Note the presence of `cuda-12.3`:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/cuda-12.3/bin
```

I updated `/etc/environment` to include this line:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/cuda-12.3/bin"
```

That is sufficient to set `$PATH` for users and for root.

```
username:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/cuda-12.3/bin
```

```
$ sudo su
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/cuda-12.3/bin
```

It is also sufficient to update path when launching `byobu` as a regular user.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/cuda-12.3/bin
```

The issue occurs when I start `sudo byobu` and get the `$PATH`.

```
$ sudo byobu
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```

Notice that `cuda-12.3` is missing, as are other directories.

I tried editing the following locations, but all failed to set `$PATH` correctly when running `sudo byobu`.

- `/etc/profile`
- `/usr/share/byobu/profiles`
- `/root/.profile`

I have referred to these posts:

- [PATH variable not getting updated according to /etc/environment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/817766/path-variable-not-getting-updated-according-to-etc-environment)
- [Where is the system-wide $PATH variable set?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633525/where-is-the-system-wide-path-variable-set)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix

Comment: `PATH` is going to get reset by the default sudoers `env_reset` policy - unless it's added by way of `env_keep`