# Where should I put my script so that I can run it by a direct command?

Tags: command-line, scripts

Where can (should) I put my (bash) script so that it can be used (forever) by terminal or by a direct command: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>?

I know there is `/usr/bin` and `/sbin` & `/bin`directories but when should I use between them?

Where should I put my script?

Comment: Please read [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/308045/differences-between-bin-sbin-usr-bin-usr-sbin-usr-local-bin-usr-local), and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/406250/is-it-safe-to-place-symlinks-in-bin-directory) questions to understand all about this directories

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Don't use these directories:

> `/usr/bin`, `/sbin` and `/bin`

Leave them for package-managed executables.

---

If you need the script for one user, [waltinator's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/465113) is fine.

If you need the script for all users on your system (but you can also use this for one user), stick it in [**`/usr/local/bin/`**](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY). One advantage: this directory is already in your PATH so there is no need to edit files.

Comment: At least in my installation of Ubuntu 14.04, executables in /usr/local/bin are not available to cron jobs (run by the web user). However, programs in /usr/bin are.

Comment: And how do I run my `.sh` file? Take a `hello-world.sh` file for example.

Comment: @EnriqueBermúdez put `#!/bin/sh` at the first line, `chmod` it `+x` and put it in `/usr/local/bin/`. The extension is not needed. when you run it it will execute your script with `/bin/sh`. You can also put `/bin/node` there for a javascript file.

Answer (score 103):

It depends on who will use your script:

- **Only you** - `$HOME/.local/bin` (As per the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html))
- **You and other local users** - `/usr/local/bin`
- **`root` only** - `/usr/local/sbin`

That way you have your own scripts separated from the distribution-provided binaries.

Comment: Traditionally, the `.../sbin` directories are used for statically-linked binaries (mostly used by `root`, before shared libraries are available), not user scripts.

Comment: That only applies to `/sbin`, not `/usr/sbin` or `/usr/local/sbin`. The Filesystem Hierarchy Standard states that "_Locally installed system administration programs should be placed in /usr/local/sbin._" [\[link\]](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#FTN.AEN1540).

Comment: This is all true, but the `sbin` directories are being phased out and there really is no reason to separate them. For more on that, see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125311/22222).

Comment: I see a _discussion_ about phasing them out, and while the arguments are compelling, the current recommendation is the one I quoted above.

Comment: And, four years later, the recommendation still stands: [FHS 3.0](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s10.html)

Comment: @Twinkles Is there any reason against putting user scripts in `~/.local/bin`? (which is already in the `PATH` in a couple distributions)

Comment: No, that's perfectly fine. In fact, should the executable be placed in the home directory automatically by a software, I'd recommend it.

Comment: Would you expect `$HOME/.local/bin` to be precreated on a ubuntu install? It wasn't for me nor is it in my $PATH. (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on WSL2)

Comment: The XDG Desktop Specification asks distributions to add `$HOME/.local/bin` to `$PATH`. Ubuntu only does so if that directory exists. So, after you create that folder, simply `source ~/.profile` or log out and back in to have it in your PATH.

Answer (score 58):

You should put your script under `$HOME/bin`. Follow below PATH to achieve this:

1. Create a folder using `mkdir $HOME/bin`
2. Then put your script in `$HOME/bin`
3. Finally, add the following line under `$HOME/.bashrc` by editing with `gedit $HOME/.bashrc`

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

When the system is looking for the command you typed, it will look in each directory of `$PATH` and execute the first match it finds.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. *First* put it in $HOME/bin, then create the directory? Also, scripts in $HOME/bin are found by default, no need to add it to $PATH.

Comment: @JacobVlijm: It's "found by default" since it's added to $PATH in `~/.profile`. ;)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson You are right, what I meant was: so you do'nt need to add it add it *once more* :)

Comment: Adding $HOME/bin to the start of your path will make sure your scripts get seen before any elsewhere on the system. While this is convenient, it opens you up to all sorts of unexpected behaviors if one or more of your scripts has the same name as a command somewhere else in your path. This could potentially open security vulnerabilities as it it is much easier to gain access to a user account than one with elevated privileges. E.g. someone adding a script named ls to your bin directory that really runs an rm -rf *  . Adding your $HOME/bin to the end of your path avoids most such problems.

Comment: @Joe If they have write access to `$HOME/bin`, then they can already `rm -rf ~`. I always prefer prepending custom paths, since it's an explicit decision I've made.

Comment: @Sparhawk - It's a personal preference. The reasons I advise against it are (only if you use custom programs with names of existing commands): 1) you get used to it and then it doesn't work when you are on another system and 2) if anyone else uses your system (e.g. to help you debug a problem), then they get unexpected behavior for commands with the same names. If you don't use the same names, then it's just faster to prepend the path as you do.

Comment: @Joe Yes, I agree that it's a personal preference, but I was just mentioning that others may have different preferences. FWIW I also have things like `alias cp='cp -i --preserve=all'` on my system, so I certainly don't use a "default" system. I copy my `.bashrc` to new servers, etc.

Comment: @Joe fwiw, Ubuntu prepends.  It has this in the default profile:  PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"

Comment: what about ~/.local/bin

Comment: Just had the same question: `~/.local/bin` is already in the `PATH`. Any reason against using it for personal scripts?

Comment: I'm disinclined to put scripts in `~/.local/bin` as tools like `pip` will also install to that directory.