# Should I save my scripts with the .sh extension?

Tags: scripts

I have some functional scripts and I want to copy to `/usr/bin` I want to use them as normal terminal commands. Is it a good practice to use them with the `.sh` extension or can I save them without extension?

Comment: Also if you want those scripts to be available to all users, `/usr/local/bin` may be a better choice.

Comment: @Salem `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` should both be available to all users, but `/usr/local/bin` is better for executables that are not part of packages.

Comment: The only benefit I've seen is that editors such as vim or nano know how to highlight right from the start, and that's about it.

Comment: @rath I get syntax highlighting without the extension if I have the shebang set to `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: @Sparhawk Indeed but I often forget it till I try to run the script ;)

Comment: @gerrit, Do you mind elaborating? Why `/usr/local/bin` is better for executables that are not part of packages?

Comment: @Pacerier That's a separate question that I'm sure many others can answer a lot better than me.  I'd just say "it's the standard".

Comment: @rath, that seems like a pretty good reason to do it then, no?

Comment: @rath, what version of vim are you using that can't figure out syntax highlighting from the shebang?

Comment: More useful would be to have shebangs on top so whatever program you use to run them will recognize them quickly.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

No, it is not a good practice, you should keep your scripts without extension. Note, that scripts being part of packages doesn't have a *.sh* extension, i.e. *update-grub*, not *update-grub.sh*. If you are still not convinced, then be advised, that [Google Shell Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml#File_Extensions) says:

> **Executables should have no extension (strongly preferred)** or a .sh extension. Libraries must have a .sh extension and should not be executable.

PS You don't have to put your script into `/bin`. You can create directory `~/bin` and put your script there. Directory `~/bin` is included in `$PATH` by default, so scripts put there can be run as any other shell command.

Comment: *"Directory ~/bin is included in `$PATH` by default"* - Since when? Anyway, `~/.local/bin` is probably a better choice as it's a standard.

Comment: You mean "Libraries must have a .so extension", right? Not sh.

Comment: @KeithWolters first, not me, but Google. Second, .sh, not .so, we are talking about shell scripts, not binaries.

Comment: The Google style guide is very specific to Google. For example, "Bash is the only shell scripting language permitted for executables." Clearly an internal rule rather than best practices.

Comment: @PaulDraper  Note, that scripts being part of packages doesn't have a .sh extension, i.e. update-grub, not update-grub.sh.

Comment: @nyuszika7h check out ~/.profile... it inserts $HOME/bin into your path if the directory exists

Comment: For what it's worth, the bash-4.4 tag has many files beginning with #!/bin/sh sporting a .sh extension.  I'd sooner consider GNU an authority than Google.  The ultimate advantage is for the coder.  Someone looking to modify an executables behavior can recognize the .sh extension immediately and happily edit in vi.  Otherwise, it's off to search for source code, recompile.  Omitting the extension just complicates this.  It also makes grep far less specific.  As this is programmer's land, I say keep the .sh.

Comment: Would upvote an answer that actually says **why** script files should not end in `.sh`.

Comment: @BobStein See https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/, and the history of freenode #bash channel factoids on the topic at http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/.sh

Comment: @Brian, the essay linked above may be of interest to you as well.

Answer (score 11):

I second the recommendation to use `~/bin` which gets automatically added to your `$PATH`,as [Sergey](https://askubuntu.com/users/14564/sergey) said. Or `/usr/local/bin`, which may already be on the `PATH`.
However:

- You are doing this for yourself. Use whatever you feel comfortable with. Indeed, I'd say keep the extension so that you'll be reminded it's your script you are running, since -
- Extensions are uncommon in `/usr/bin`. In my system, I can find only two:

  ```
  $ dpkg -S `ls /usr/bin/*.sh`
  mtools: /usr/bin/amuFormat.sh
  gettext-base: /usr/bin/gettext.sh
  ```

  So if you are packaging, definitely leave out the extension.

Comment: `~/bin` is added to the `$PATH` automatically if it exists, no need to add it manually. Just create the directory, log out and log back in.

Answer (score 7):

Just put following line at top of file:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

So-that file will be automatically type : **Shell Script** without any extension!

Remember to give execution permission to file.

For putting script so-that can be run by direct command, visit: [Where should I put my script so that I can run it by a direct command?](https://askubuntu.com/q/465109)

Comment: Or even just #!/bin/sh if you don't need the full bash shell.

Comment: Many OSs link /bin/sh and /bin/bash

Comment: @MaxCoplan, when started under the name `sh`, bash turns off many of its features. They're thus not identical even when linked.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that is definitely true.  I was but a young and naive fool when I wrote this :)

Answer (score 1):

### Your scripts and the commands that run them don't need to have the same name

I agree with the opinions and advice in other answers here, in that typed commands shouldn't have an extension (`mycmd`, not `mycmd.sh`), and that editors should be able to identify the file contents from the shebang line (e.g. `#!/bin/bash`).

However, if the scripts are part of a larger project, I find it useful to have file name extensions on them to remind myself whether the files in the repo are editable (e.g. scripts, source code), or compiled binary files.

To achieve both aims, you can **symlink your scripts from the directory on your PATH**. E.g. if `~/.local/bin` is on your PATH:

```bash
cd ~/.local/bin
ln -s ../../path/to/code/project/src/mycmd.sh mycmd

# now mycmd is on the PATH, and calling mycmd runs the script mycmd.sh
cd somewhere/else
mycmd
```

This also allows you to do version control from `~/path/to/code/project/`, without then having to copy the files into a directory on your PATH when you do a "release".