# Start a programs in terminal only by name

Tags: command-line, software-installation, programming

I'm new to the Linux environment and I noticed there are many programs of which we can use only the program name to start them in the Linux terminal.

E.g. `gedit`, `vi`, `firefox`

Instead of providing all of the program's path, I would like to run my own programs like this in the terminal by only typing the program name. Programs I like to run are written in Java and Python and script files (.jar, .pyc, .py and .class)

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Hint: All the programs that run by name in the terminal are on your path. I believe the .jar, .pyc, .py and .class files you mention need to be interpreted to run so if I'm correct, CLI won't work for these

Comment: Possible cross site post [How to set a program to run in Linux terminal only with program name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28306266/3789550)

Comment: please also read: http://askubuntu.com/questions/465109/where-should-i-put-my-script-so-that-i-can-run-it-by-a-direct-command/465162#465162

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you want to execute a file called `fun.py` located on your Desktop using the command `funny`. Obviously, you'll need python for that, so the exact bash command would be `python ~/Desktop/fun.py`.

**How to do that without having to change the PATH variable:**

First create a file called `funny` with the following contents:

```
#! /bin/sh
python ~/Desktop/fun.py
```

and save it to a folder (let's say you have saved it on your Desktop folder).

If non-existent, create a folder named `bin` in your home directory.
Then execute the following commands from a terminal:

```
source .profile
chmod +x ~/Desktop/funny
mv ~/Desktop/funny ~/bin
```

You can now enter the command `funny` to execute the python script.

Comment: it worked thank you for explain it very briefly

Comment: Also an interesting post with a few good answers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/465109/where-should-i-put-my-script-so-that-i-can-run-it-by-a-direct-command/465162#465162

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this you need to update your execution PATH variable.
To see your PATH variable you can type
`echo $PATH` in a terminal
These are the places that bash will look for your executable files going from left to right.

To add a directory for bash to search for executables you do 1 of 2 things.

1. Add the files you want to run into one of the PATH directories.

Or

2. Add a new directory to your path

For option 1.

If your `PATH=/usr/bin`
You could copy the programs you want to execute to there.

For option 2

if you made a new directory with all your programs in 
`/home/bob/bin`
You could you could add this to your PATH by editing the .bashrc file at the very end add this line:
`PATH=$PATH:/home/bob/bin`

then to load those .bashrc changes type `source .bashrc`

Comment: is there any thing to update in .profile file

Comment: You optionally can but the `.bashrc` should work.  You can see the differences here:
http://superuser.com/questions/278433/whats-the-difference-between-profile-and-bash-profile-and-when-do-you-config

Answer (score 0):

I think /usr/local/bin is a preferred place for user created scripts, etc which you want to start just using name. Anything you copy there can be started simply by name since that is in $PATH.  To verify what your $PATH contents type:

```
echo $PATH
```

For running bash, sh, or any scripts make sure you have "allow execution" set for the file:

```
chmod +x  my_script
```

Related to to running "python my_code.py" or similar things which may require parameters you can create a tiny script which will start that and locate the script into /usr/local/bin.