# I want the date and time to be added in a text file whenever I open it

Tags: command-line, text-editor

I was using windows 7,8.1, and 10 previously and there was an option in the Notepad that if I type .LOG at the beginning of the file (which is done only once), every time I open the notepad the date and current time will be automatically added.

Basically, I keep track of all my expenses and it's very important for me to just open the text file and it automatically adds the date and time for me. How can I do this in Ubuntu 15.04?

Comment: Will you be using gedit?

Comment: yes i will use gedit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple.

```
#!/bin/bash
filetoedit="$1"
if [ "$(head -n 1 $filetoedit)" = ".LOG" ] ; then
    date >>$filetoedit
fi
vim "$filetoedit"
```

Put the above script in a file in your `$PATH`, make it executable and call your editor through it i.e. if you save it as `open.sh`, then open any file e.g. `foo.txt` for editing as :

```
open.sh foo.txt
```

You can adjust the date format (see `man date`), and change the editor used by replacing `vim` with your choice.

See ["Where should I put my script so that I can run it by a direct command?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465109/where-should-i-put-my-script-so-that-i-can-run-it-by-a-direct-command/465113)