# Make Ctrl-Alt-T to open a terminal tab if any terminal was open

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

Is there a way to get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal tab, if you already have an open terminal, instead of another terminal window?

I have already changed my preferences to open new terminals in tab. 
(I still want the key binding to open a terminal if none are open.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I've done and it did the job pretty good.

1. change `gnome-terminal` preferences to default if you have changed it.
   so, set the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> as shortcut for opening a new tab.

   [image]
2. We need `xdotool` (it's around 30KB) install it via:

   ```
   sudo apt install xdotool
   ```
3. Now create a file (e.g in your home named `.custom-terminal-key.sh`) and put these lines in it (Thanks to Jacob Vlijm):

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash

   if [[ "$(xprop -id "$(xdotool getactivewindow)" WM_CLASS)" == *"gnome-terminal"* ]]; then
     sleep 0.1
     xdotool key ctrl+shift+t
   elif ! pgrep 'gnome-terminal'; then
     gnome-terminal
   fi
   ```

   Every time we run it, if any `gnome-terminal` was open, it will simulate a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> key binding, otherwise it runs `gnome-terminal`.
4. Finally we change the default behavior of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, instead of opening a terminal every time you press these, it will run our script.

   ```bsh
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec '/home/USER/.custom-terminal-key.sh'
   ```

   Change `USER` with your real *username*.
5. Don't forget to give our script the executable bit:

   ```bsh
   chmod +x ~/.custom-terminal-key.sh
   ```

We are done.

---

#### Rollback

Whenever you changed your mind just run:

```bsh
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'gnome-terminal'
```

Remove our script `rm ~/.custom-terminal-key.sh` and `xdotool`: `sudo apt remove xdotool`.

---

*[Getting active window name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81898/64321)*

Comment: maybe add a condition to check if the gnome-terminal window is the active one, raise it if not. Else the command might end up on the wrong application.

Comment: Still it works when the window is active, but not if it isn't. I don't think the answer you use in the link is the best on that question though :)

Comment: Yeah, and I think it shouldn't; About finding the window name, I used it to get the process name (command) easier ;)

Comment: Bash is not really my thing, but if that's your decision, this http://paste.ubuntu.com/24468812/ might be shorter. You can simply chain xdotool window commands.

Comment: Ah wait, you'd still have to launch the terminal if not running: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24468949/. Furthermore, I don't have the key `org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal` (unity/16.04) You might want to mention the manual way, using Settings > keyboard.

Comment: @JacobVlijm thanks updated with a minor edit ;) Are you sure about the key? cause when I run : `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec` it gives me `x-terminal-emulator` on 16.04 unity.

Comment: Huh? you are right! I must be blind or something, but I don't see it in dconf-editor. From cli, it is there. Anyway, nice concept :) Thanks for editing, +1

Comment: Based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/465162/618307), I placed the .sh file in `usr/local/bin` and changed steps 4 and 5 accordingly.  Unfortunately, couldn't get it to work. :/

Comment: @KT12 Do exactly as the instructions, use the full path. it'll works.

Comment: Unfortunately, couldn't get it to work, but since others did, will award the correct answer to yours. Thank you!

Comment: @KT12 You should diagnose what is not working for you, e.g set another program (say `gedit`) instead of our script to see if our key binding are working ... first find which part does not work for you so we can work on it.