# ctrl-alt-t opens new terminal window instead of new tab while gnome terminal is active window

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell

<kbd>ctrl-alt-t</kbd> opens a new window instead of a new tab while the shell is the active window. I see in the terminal shortcut settings --*which are enabled*-- (in terminal window: edit > preferences > shortcuts) that <kbd>ctrl-alt-t</kbd> is meant to open a new tab.

Prior to this issue I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909305/make-ctrl-alt-t-to-open-a-terminal-tab-if-any-terminal-was-open) to try to customize the shortcut, and I then followed the "rollback" directions in that post to undo it since it wasn't working. Maybe that's what messed things up for me?

Steps to create this issue: 
1. open a gnome-shell terminal window 
2. mouse click on the terminal to ensure it is active 
3. <kbd>ctrl-alt-t</kbd>

Expected result: new terminal tab opens in existing window. 
Observed result: new and separate terminal window opens.

`gnome-shell --version` is "GNOME Shell 3.28.3"

Edit: Here is a screenshot of the terminal shortcut page. I must have somehow changed the default ctrl-shift-tab to ctrl-alt-tab?

[image]

Comment: The answer you link is though probably the right one. Would you please try again to activate shortcuts in Gnome terminal, then close and re-open it to be sure that modifications are applied, and then add a screenshot of the shortcuts in your post?

Comment: The default key to open a new tab is Ctrl+Shift+t (not Alt). With respect to Ctrl+Alt+Tab, this by default is a system wide hotkey to launch the terminal. Is your question really about the latter (I am confused since you say "ctrl-alt-t is meant to open a new tab.": no, its ctrl+shift+t).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly mistake... turns out ctrl-alt-t was set as both the new terminal tab shortcut (in terminal preferences) and also the new terminal window shortcut (in keyboard preferences). I simply edited the terminal shortcut back to ctrl-shift-t.

Thanks all for the insights and sending me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

Dont mess with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>

Open **new terminal** window: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>
Open **new tab** in an active terminal window: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>

Comment: happened to me, reading is hard... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The default hotkey in gnome-terminal to open a new tab is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Probably, you did not properly reset that key to the default when reverting the change you made according to [the question you linked to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909305/make-ctrl-alt-t-to-open-a-terminal-tab-if-any-terminal-was-open).

The behaviour where you see <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> opening a new terminal window, is perfectly normmal in a default Ubuntu install. That key combination is system wide defined to open a new terminal (*see* Settings - Keyboard).

To restore the default behaviour, change the assignment of the hotkey to open a new tab back to Shift+Ctrl+Tab in Nautilus preferences. Then you will have fully undone the changes you applied.