# Editing bashrc to run a program from the terminal

Tags: bash, bashrc

Trying to skill up in Linux. I have written a bash script to google search from the terminal. It works adequately an I run it by typing

> ~/WHAT. 
>   So far so good. I can also run it using
>   ./WHAT.

I then edit the bashrc file and add this at the end

> alias < WHAT >='./WHAT'

But then when I run

> source ~/.bashrc

I get the error

> =./WHAT: No such file or directory

Where have have I gone wrong? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Show us the text verbatim please: obfuscations like `< THE ALIAS NAME >` are unhelpful here

Comment: what is FILENAME and THE ALIAS NAME? I could help if you would describe these

Comment: IMHO your objective would be better achieved by placing your script somewhere like `~/bin` and simply making sure that `$HOME/bin` is added to your `PATH`

Comment: Use the full path in bash scripts. ~ and ./ are ambiguous. Also, if you place the script in ~/bin you do not even need an alias as it will be in your path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really added

```
alias < WHAT >='./WHAT'
```

you're misunderstanding Bash syntax. Read and re-read `man bash`. What you want is probably

```
alias WHAT='./WHAT'
```

but that's not what you want at all. See [my answer over here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465109/where-should-i-put-my-script-so-that-i-can-run-it-by-a-direct-command/465113#465113)

Comment: your link is hthttps://  should'nt it be https://

Comment: @Camden Thank you very much. I fixed the typo. I must remember to test links before posting them.

Comment: @crissixpaul Then please `Accept` my answer, so I can get more reputation points, and, eventually, Rule The World. TQ