# rtcwake‬‬: command not found | ubuntu 14.10

Tags: command-line, wakeup

when i use `rtcwake` command‬‬:

```
rtcwake‬‬: command not found
```

Searching yields nothing:

```
$ sudo apt-cache search rtcwake
$ sudo apt-get install rtcwake
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package rtcwake
```

apt-cache policy util-linux:

```
util-linux:
  Installed: 2.25.1-3ubuntu4
  Candidate: 2.25.1-3ubuntu4
  Version table:
 *** 2.25.1-3ubuntu4 0
        500 http://mirror.rol.ru/ubuntu/ utopic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: `rtcwake` is in the `util-linux` package. What is the output of `apt-cache policy util-linux`?

Comment: Post edited
THX

Comment: Try running `/usr/sbin/rtcwake`.

Comment: Oh, it worke (Thank you)

How can I use this command directly?

Comment: Try the second solution (not `sudo ln ...`)

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/sbin` contains executables/scripts than can only be run by root user or with sudo. So I think it should be accessible when you add a `sudo` on the left of your command. You will need root privileges to get it to work anyway.
More info at the following link about [difference between /bin and /sbin](https://askubuntu.com/a/308048/367990)

However, I can locate `rtcwake` without `sudo`. It opens the help screen. But sudo is required to run it anyway.