# How do I add my own Python program to the terminal?

Tags: command-line, python

I want to be able to make a Python program and then execute it in the terminal no matter which directory I am currently located in. I mean, if I have an executable Python file *and* I'm in the same folder of the file I can directly execute it but if I'm in other directories I can't.

I want to be able to execute it from anywhere as I do with all the terminal commands. I think it has to do with the PATH but I'm pretty new to Linux, so I'd appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Put the file in /usr/local/bin/ That directory is intented for binaries that are local (ie. yours)

Comment: ...and a bunch more :)

Comment: Can the file be put in /bin ? This is where I normally put my scripts

Comment: @RumeshSudhaharan if you mean `~/bin`, yes, `/bin` is not an appropriate location for user scripts.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I put my scripts in `/bin` is there any particular reason that location is not advisable? I may have to move my scripts if it will affect my computer

Comment: @RumeshSudhaharan Look here: http://askubuntu.com/a/308048/72216 It has a great answer, saying: */bin : For binaries usable before the /usr partition is mounted. This is used for trivial binaries used in the very early boot stage or ones that you need to have available in booting single-user mode. Think of binaries like cat, ls, etc.*. I prefer keeping my "own" scripts in `~/bin`.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thanks for the reply. I guess I'll move my files to `/usr/local/bin` now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an alias to `~/.bashrc`:

```
<<< "alias mypythonscript='python <path_to_python_script>'" tee -a ~/.bashrc
```

<sub>*<path_to_script> = path to your `python` script</sub>

Then update `~/.bashrc`:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

This way you'll be able to call your script from any `bash` instance by running `mypythonscript`