# mysqldump / mysql error in WP-DBManager

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, lamp

I am getting an error with the Wordpress WP-DBManager Plugin:

```
MYSQL dump path does NOT exist. Please check your mysqldump path under DB Options. 
If uncertain, contact your server administrator.

MYSQL path does NOT exist. Please check your mysql path under DB Options. 
If uncertain, contact your server administrator.
```

IT Server administrator doesn't know what to do. So I have referred to [this article](https://www.hacksparrow.com/wp-dbmanager-error-mysql-dump-path-does-not-exist-please-check-your-mysqldump-path-under-db-options.html).

I am running AWS, Ubuntu LAMP stack - mysql 5.6, php7.0

I have checked `/usr/bin` and no `mysqldump` or `mysql` folder.

In the `php.ini` file there is this line `;open_basedir =`

Do I create `mysqldump` and `mysql` folders? And set `open_basedir` to `open_basedir = /usr/bin/`?

Or based on that article there were modules to add - `<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>`. I could not find the `httpd.conf` file. Where would I find this file? Or do I create the file?

Comment: 1. Are you sure it is Ubuntu LAMP stack or it is something like as [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)? 
2. You can use `which mysql` (also `locate mysql` or `whereis mysql`) to find it.
3. `mysqldump` is a part of `mysql-client` package: `sudo apt install mysql-client` /  `sudo apt install mysql-client-5.6`. 
4. Please do not create any folders or files under `/usr/bin` if you don't know what exactly doing.
5. Within nowadays Ubuntu's versions equivalent of `httpd.conf` is the file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

Comment: [Differences between /bin, /sbin, /usr/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/sbin](http://askubuntu.com/questions/308045/differences-between-bin-sbin-usr-bin-usr-sbin-usr-local-bin-usr-local)

Comment: Hi there thanks for the feedback. I am running a vagrant/vbox locally with same specs for dev. The folders /usr/bin/mysqldump and mulitple other mysql folders are there. When I type in mysql -v i get this: The program 'mysql' can be found in the following packages:
 * mysql-client-core-5.5
 * mariadb-client-core-5.5
 * mysql-client-core-5.6
 * percona-xtradb-cluster-client-5.5
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>

Comment: locate mysql gives me a bunch of folder locations, none of which are /usr/bin

Comment: Should I install mysql-client-core-5.6 ? or just sudo apt install mysql-client - and this will get the latest? I am wondering if this will cause any issues if I do this? i.e website crash? I assume not, but just want to make sure

Comment: Thanks Spas Spasov installing mysql-client worked `sudo apt install mysql-client` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql` - the MySQL command-line tool is a simple SQL shell with input line editing capabilities. It supports interactive and noninteractive use.

`mysqldump` - is a command-line client program, it is used to dump local or remote MySQL database or collection of databases for backup into a single flat file.

They can be found in several packages. For example in Ubuntu [16.04 LTS](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/mysqldump.1.html) both are part of the package `mysql-client`:

```
sudo apt install mysql-client
```

[`mysql-client`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/database/mysql-client) is *metapackage depending on the latest version*. While [`mysql-client-5.x`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/mysql-client-5.7) consists of binaries of exact version `5.x`.

**Please note that `mysql` and `mysqld` are different 'things'!**

`mysqld`, also known as MySQL Server - is the main program that does most of the work in a MySQL installation.

---

Further Reading:

- [Ubuntu Documentation: MySQL](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/mysql.html)
- [Ubuntu Manuals: MySQL](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/mysql.1.html)
- [Ubuntu Manuals: MySQLDump](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/mysqldump.1.htmlhttp://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/mysqldump.1.html)
- [Ubuntu Manuals: MySQLHotCopy](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/mysqlhotcopy.1.html)
- [Ubuntu Manuals: AutoMySQLBackup](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/automysqlbackup.8.html)
- [Ubuntu Manuals: MySQL server](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/mysqld.8.html)