# What is the difference between local and .local in ubuntu?

Tags: filesystem, paths

Echoing path in ubuntu returns following colon separated paths,

```
/home/stack/bin:/home/stack/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

In these paths at some places there is local while at others .local is used what is the difference between both?

Comment: local is a folder; .local is a hidden folder.

Comment: Hey thanks, and are they same folders, hidden in one case and visible in other? Or they are completely different? What is the reason for hiding local in later case?

Comment: Obviously not the same folders. Example:  /home/stack/.local and /usr/local The reason for hiding is because typically those folders are at your home but aren't for you to use, just to store configs and such.

Comment: For more info about local folders in general, see [What is /usr/local/bin?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4186/117037)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in this particular case, `local` is a visible directory, and `.local` is a hidden directory. you can see list of all hidden directory and/or files in a certain directory using `ls -a` or `ls .*` command.

Answer (score 10):

Note that the `.local` is used in only one place: inside your home directory. The others are all `/usr/local`. `/usr/local` is where programs installed outside of the package manager are supposed to add things, so various folders in it are added to `PATH` by default.

`~/.local` is analogous to `/usr/local`, but for programs installing (or otherwise writing data) to your home directory (for example, `pip`), so `.local/bin` is also added to `PATH`. The directory structure in `.local` is similar to that of `/usr/local`, which in turn is like that of `/usr`.

For more information, see:

- [Differences between /bin, /sbin, /usr/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/sbin](https://askubuntu.com/q/308045/760903)
- [How to understand the Ubuntu file system layout?](https://askubuntu.com/q/138547/760903)

Answer (score 2):

Files and directories with a preceding `.` are hidden items.