# Where should I put my Bash scripts?

Tags: bash, scripts, sudo

I have a few very simple Bash scripts that I cobbled together for things that I do regularly.

One of them is to run [duplicity](https://duplicity.gitlab.io/) to do my backup tasks. Nothing clever, just a bunch of `if .. then` statements really.

As this needs to be run as root, would it be best practice to put my script in `/usr/bin` (or another location on PATH), `chown` to root:root and `chmod` to 700?

Comment: I would say use `git` to version-control your scripts, put local copies of the git repos somewhere you like in `~`, and then symlink the scripts into `~/bin`.

Comment: You mean `git` as in `github` in the clouds?

Comment: I think he means for you to create local repositories with `git` (on your machine only) not remote ones like those on `github`. This latter would only be useful if you wanted to share your scripts with others.

Comment: @IanC I enjoy sharing my scripts but posting them here in AskUbuntu makes more sense to the limited audience.  If `git` is anything like `github` I feel overwhelmed thinking about the learning curve.

Comment: @edwinksl the think I don't like about putting them in `/home/me/bin` is remembering to get new user accounts permission to the directory and putting it in their path. Is there a disadvantage to `/usr/local` like it goes **poof** when an upgrade is done?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix If you want your scripts to be available to other users, you should put them in `/usr/local/bin`. Otherwise, I would say just put them in `~/bin`. Your own scripts in both directories should be safe when you upgrade.

Comment: As above, place them in /usr/local/bin. Just make sure your script names are unique & not an existing linux command/binary name. Myself just add a number to end of any script I create as I haven't seen any pre-existing linux names end in a number. ( not to say some really obscure ones may...

Comment: @doug the number suffix would also come in handy when you are testing different flavors of your scripts.

Comment: @edwinksl my apologies L.D.James just explained to me how `~/bin` is dynamically placed in PATH$ during login.

Comment: @edwinksl Almost a year later I have to say `~/bin` is the best place for most scripts as you don't have to use `sudo` to edit them as you do when they are stored in `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I save my own scripts in `/opt/scripts`.

If your script should executeable by every system user, you can create a symbolic link to `/usr/bin`.

If only root should execute the script, you can create a symbolic link to `/usr/sbin`.

Command to add a symbolic link in `/usr/bin/`:

```
ln -s /opt/scripts/<script> /usr/bin/
```

You can execute the script, because `/usr/bin/` is in your *PATH* by default.

Comment: I would recommend that instead of using `/usr/bin` as the target for user/local shell script - that it be `/usr/local/bin` (or `/opt/bin`) as per [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard - Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/FilesystemHierarchyStandard) to avoid conflicts (most of the time, you want Ubuntu's provided scripts to take precedence).

Comment: On most systems ``/usr/local/bin`` overrides ``/usr/bin``, as it comes later in the path. This is on purpose, as the system does not put files there, so you can put files there, which SHOULD override the system provided ones.

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer, even though both answers seem fine. Reason is, I eneded up taking a look at the FHS docs and came away with the understanding that /opt is there for exactly this purpose. I like the idea of them simply sym linking to my scripts in /usr/local/bin. Thanks for all the pointers.

Answer (score 27):

### If no other user other than you uses these scripts

Then you can keep them in `/home/$USER/bin`. Create the `bin` directory if it doesn't exist and move the files there. The `bin` directory in your home will automatically get added to the PATH environment variable. The code is in the `.profile`:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

See [How to add /home/username/bin to $PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402353/how-to-add-home-username-bin-to-path)

Or in some systems it may be in `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=${HOME}/bin/:${HOME}/.local/bin:${PATH}
```

Thanks [Elder Geek](https://askubuntu.com/users/225694/elder-geek).

### If these script are to be used by other users:

Then either `/usr/local/bin` or `/opt/bin` are good options. See [Is there a standard place for placing custom Linux scripts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195652/is-there-a-standard-place-for-placing-custom-linux-scripts)

Comment: For user-specific scripts and binaries there's `~/.local/bin`. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36871/where-should-a-local-executable-be-placed) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316765/which-distributions-have-home-local-bin-in-path) for explanations.

Answer (score 3):

I have a directory that I use for the quick collection of my local tools or things that I deploy on various computers in `/usr/local/apollo`.  There are branches off this directory for `flags`, `bin` and `logs`.

For the applications that I download and install outside of the default `apt-get` repositories are placed in `/opt/` and a directory by the app's name, with one more sub-directory for the specific version of the application.  This way my compiled version of an application like `vlc` or `eclipse` won't conflict with the distributed version.

My use of `/opt` is the way it's basically officially designed.

By the way the directories `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/apollo`, and `/opt` survives a fresh OS version installation overwrite.

Comment: `$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin` I like the fact `/usr/local/bin` is already in the path one less thing to remember. I like your method of `/opt/program/version` I can use that for Kernel stuff I get and compile like EnhanceIO where they change things between kernel versions. Is `/apollo` a moon landing personal favorite or does it have Ubuntu meaning?

Comment: What is the difference between `/usr/local/bin` and `usr/local/sbin` such that the latter gets nuked during upgrades?

Comment: The installer Nukes the directories that it uses.  It conveniently creates `/usr/local` directories, but it doesn't put anything in any of them.  Those directories are populated by the user.  Many source programs outside the repositories give the user the option of selecting where they want the install to go.  The default in the config files are `/usr/local/bin` .  So because of how common it is to use those directories, they are included in the user's path by default.  By default the system checks for `~/bin`  and adds it to the path if it exists.

Comment: You mean the system checks for `~/bin` during install or every boot? What is the difference between `sbin` and `bin`? They seem to coexist there must be quasi-rules on which you pick based on program type right?

Comment: Apollo was the name of a band I had when I was young.  It because the name of my company later.  Apollo is named after the Greek God Apollo.  The `/usr/local/sbin` is for system applications that are compiled on the local.  The `/usr/local/bin` is for general applications compiled on the local machine.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix On the `~/bin` path... it's not added during installation.  The system checks for it on every login and adds it to the $PATH if it exist during the login.  Look at the last two lines of your `~/.profile` settings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45937/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-wineunuuchs2unix).