# What is the difference between `$HOME/bin` and `$HOME/.local/bin` ? When to use use one over the other?

Tags: bash, home-directory

According to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/713131/a-pip-install-for-jupyter-notebook-puts-its-binaries-in-local-bin-and-then-i), `$HOME/.local/bin` is used to store user-specific binaries. But I see in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998452/where-should-i-put-my-bash-scripts) that `$HOME/bin` serves a similar purpose.

What am I missing? When should I use one over the other?

I know about the difference between `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`. Is it the same here?

I also know about hidden directories and files.

Both work : I'm looking for a rule or a convention to help me choose one or the other.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's up to you where to store your binaries. You can create any directory you like. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that `$HOME/.local/bin` is a hidden directory.

It doesn't matter where you store your binaries. You can store them e.g. in `$HOME/binaries`.

It won't change anything.

Comment: You can always add anything you like to $PATH.

Comment: And also `$HOME/bin` isn't added by default.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know about hidden directories and how adding a directory to `PATH` works. I was really only just looking for an explanation for a convention, what is the most UNIX/Linux-like way of doing things or if it's a unique quirk from Ubuntu.

Comment: If you add a directory to $PATH, you won't need to type the full path when run something. There is no "convention" for that. It is like "where do I store my photos".

Comment: But `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` are both in `$PATH` but you're not supposed to add the same type of binary in them. `/usr/bin` contains system executables managed by the package manager, while `/usr/local/bin` contains "manually" installed executables. Both work, but it's good practice to differentiate them.

Comment: It doesn't matter what "type" of binary is in the $PATH. The only reason to add something there is to run binaries without entering a  full path.