# Running a Custom Command as Superuser Using sudo?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I've read a few posts such as [Is there a standard place for placing custom Linux scripts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195652/is-there-a-standard-place-for-placing-custom-linux-scripts) , [Where should I put my bash scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998452/where-should-i-put-my-bash-scripts) , but I still am getting an error that my script isn't being found in bash.

I've placed my script (Named Wandering_Echo) in `/usr/local/Custom_Programs` and symlinked it into `/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, and `/usr/local/sbin`, but when I try running `sudo Wandering_Echo`, I get this error:

```
sarah@LesserArk:/usr/local/Custom_Programs$ sudo Wandering_Echo ?
sudo: Wandering_Echo: command not found
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong as it is in the super-user bin directory.

Wandering_Echo does some low level filesystem operations using BTRFS, so it needs root to run.
**Edit 0:** Wandering_Echo does run as regular user, just not as super-user from terminal.

**EDIT 1:**

```
sarah@LesserArk:/usr/local/Custom_Programs$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/Wandering_Echo /usr/local/Custom_Programs/Wandering_Echo 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Aug 14 15:22 /usr/local/bin/Wandering_Echo -> Wandering_Echo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 96 Aug 14 13:09 /usr/local/Custom_Programs/Wandering_Echo
```

&

```
sarah@LesserArk:~$ sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'
[sudo] password for sarah: 
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```

Comment: `sudo ./Wandering_Echo`  or `sudo {interpreter/python/perl} Wandering_Echo`

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -l /usr/local/bin/Wandering_Echo /usr/local/Custom_Programs/Wandering_Echo` and `sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'` to your question.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch Maybe it's the execute flags? Sorry about the delay, I was running errands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

### 1.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Aug 14 15:22 /usr/local/bin/Wandering_Echo -> Wandering_Echo
```

If you access a symlink its target value is taken as a path relative to the symlink's parent folder (or as an absolute path if it starts with `/`). So this symlink doesn't point to `/usr/local/Custom_Programs/Wandering_Echo` but to itself, which isn't that useful. Remove it and use

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Custom_Programs/Wandering_Echo /usr/local/bin/Wandering_Echo
```

to create it properly. Check the other symlinks, too.

### 2.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 96 Aug 14 13:09 /usr/local/Custom_Programs/Wandering_Echo
```

As you already wrote in the comments the  execute flags are missing here. Use

```
sudo chmod u+x /usr/local/Custom_Programs/Wandering_Echo
```

to make it executable for root only. Replace `u+x` with `a+x` to make it executable for all users.