# How to get Show Desktop working for use by all users?

Tags: scripts, 22.04, .desktop

New install of Ubuntu desktop 22.04. I'm trying to get Show Desktop script working for use by all users, with icon in Left Panel of apps. I've put both a shell script show-desktop.sh permissions of 644) using wmctrl and a desktop file show-desktop.desktop with permissions of 744 in /usr/share/applications. However, I don't get Show Desktop found in Activities or Apps.
Here is show-desktop.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
```

Type=Application
Name=Show Desktop
Exec=/usr/share/applications/show-desktop.sh
Icon=desktop

Here is show-desktop.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

status="$(wmctrl -m | grep "showing the desktop" | sed -r 's/(.*)(ON|OFF)/\2/g')"

if [ $status == "ON" ]; then
wmctrl -k off
else
wmctrl -k on
fi

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.desktop` launchers are only included in the overview if the minimum of required fields is valid. In this case, the `exec=` entry is not valid: the permission of the script are set to "read only" for others. Therefore, the script is not recognized as a valid executable for users that are not the owner. Thus, make the script executable by "others".

Comment: I changed permissions of desktop file in /usr/share/applications to 777, but app still not found in Activities or Apps.

Comment: I copied your files exactly, and "Show Desktop" for me appears in the application overview, with a generic icon though because I do not have a "desktop" icon.

Answer (score 0):

Now working.
Here is my ShowDesktop.desktop file (with permissions 644) in /usr/share/applications/:
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/usr/bin/ShowDesktop.sh
Name=Show Desktop
Comment=Show Desktop
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/ShowDesktop.jpeg

Here is my ShowDesktop.sh file (with permissions 755) in /usr/bin/:
#!/bin/bash

status="$(wmctrl -m | grep "showing the desktop" | sed -r 's/(.*)(ON|OFF)/\2/g')"

if [ $status == "ON" ]; then
wmctrl -k off
else
wmctrl -k on
fi

My icon ShowDesktop.jpeg (with permissions 644) is in /usr/share/pixmaps/

The directories I used for the Exec and the Icon lines in the ShowDesktop.desktop file (/usr/bin/, /usr/share/pixmaps) were culled from previous AskUbuntu answers:
[Standard place for custom scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195652/is-there-a-standard-place-for-placing-custom-linux-scripts)
[Icon Path in Desktop File](https://askubuntu.com/questions/722179/icon-path-in-desktop-file)

Comment: Correction to my answer: /usr/bin should be /usr/local/bin in my answer.