# How to create a system-wide environmental variable?

Tags: environment-variables

I want to set an environmental variable that all users will have, where do I do this?

This is for users who login and also for certain processes that run under an account.

Comment: possible duplicated: http://askubuntu.com/q/24937/62483

Answer (score 1):

You can set it in /etc/bash.bashrc

It will be available for all the users in the machine.

Comment: so it will require a reboot then right for processes that run under accounts?

Comment: you dont have to reboot after setting it just run this command "source /etc/bash.bashrc" and your environment variable will be available for use