# How to permanently set an environment variable

Tags: environment-variables

I am completely new to Ubuntu, and I would permanently set an environment variable.
I have read [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) that I have to set `~/.profile`, but I don't know how to apply it. In my case I would permanently set `export PATH="/home/name/anaconda/bin:$PATH"`, how could I do?

Comment: @Zanna I think this is more useful (having used it myself): [How do I set PATH variables for all users on a server?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24937/how-do-i-set-path-variables-for-all-users-on-a-server). At least because the `environment` answer is the most upvoted one there :)

Comment: From ubuntu docs here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables

Comment: @vpedrosa: Since the folder to be added to PATH is in $HOME, it's unlikely that modifying PATH system wide applies here.

Comment: I had similar issue with GOPATH environment variable. I had to put export GOPATH="$HOME/path/to/workspace/", and then log back to apply the edited file

Answer (score 61, accepted):

- Open a terminal window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
- Open the file for editing with

  ```
  gedit ~/.profile
  ```
- Add the command to the bottom of the file.
- Save and close gedit.
- Log out and log in again.

Comment: Do I have  to add the entire command  `export PATH="/home/name/anaconda/bin:$PATH` at the bottom of the file?  Or I have to add it at the existing PATH?

Comment: @Simone: You should add the entire command. That way you do add the folder to the existing PATH. (Don't forget the trailing `"`, btw.)

Comment: This does it only for that particular user though.

Comment: @akki: What do you mean?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson If I update the ~/.profile file for one particular user the variable doesn't get updated for other users.
(Or are environment variables user-specific only? Are there system-wide/user-independent environment variables?)

Comment: @akki: Ok, now I see. Yes, you can set them [system wide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables) if you like.

Comment: I followed this method, now stuck in an infinite login loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Mobeen: Apparently you made a mistake. I suggest that you file a new question where you describe the problem as detailed as you can.

Comment: I think user need logout then login to reapply the updated .profile

Comment: You don't have to logout and login again. You can simply do `source ~/.profile ` to apply the changes.

Comment: @bro-grammer: Doing so would only apply them in the current terminal window. Already running processes would not be aware of the changes.

Comment: Is it correct that if you want to add the vars system wide you can use this profile file: `sudo vi /etc/profile` and add them there?