# Can't reset my JAVA_HOME to new Open JDK 11 Java installation

Tags: software-installation, java, environment-variables, jdk, openjdk

OS: UBUNTU 18.04

I had installed Oracle Java 8 earlier. But decided to switch to open JDK 11.
it's successfully installed.
*java -version

openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)*

Then I set the JAVA_HOME
*sudo nano /etc/environment* 
File changes:
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/$
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/"

Then executed:
source /etc/environment

echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/

**But the moment I exit the terminal and then launch the terminal again:**
I get this output:

**▶ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle**

which you can see is not what is expected.
Please help me out

Comment: Log out from the session and log in again. `/etc/environment` is read for the session when you log in.

Comment: I even tried that but it's still the same

Comment: Maybe the checked answer to [Find where JAVA_HOME is set](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154955/how-to-find-where-is-java-home-set/154957) will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## To Answer the question

The answers and some comments focus on how to set `JAVA_HOME` to version 11 but the question is partly about "where is version 8 being set?". To answer that see:

- [`grep`ing all files for a string takes a long time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005437/greping-all-files-for-a-string-takes-a-long-time/1005438#1005438)

Use this command:

```
$ sudo grep -rnw --exclude-dir={boot,dev,lib,media,mnt,proc,root,run,sys,/tmp,tmpfs,var} '/' -e '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle' | grep JAVA_HOME

/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh:4:export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
/etc/profile.d/jdk.csh:4:setenv JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
/home/rick/.gradle/daemon/4.6/daemon-14831.out.log:53:20:45:23.553 [DEBUG] (... SNIP ...) /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin (... SNIP ...) Configuring env variables: {PATH=/home/rick/bin:/home/rick/.local/bin:/mnt/e/bin:/mnt/e/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin,  (... SNIP ...)
```

This is what my system returns. Yours will likely be different. To make a long story short the culprit is `/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh`:

```
$ cat /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh

setenv J2SDKDIR /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
setenv J2REDIR /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
setenv PATH ${PATH}:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
setenv JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
setenv DERBY_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db
```

You probably surmise `/etc/profile.d/jdk.csh` needs changing too. Indeed it contains the exact same contents as `/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh`

---

## To address the XY problem

There is a better way than going through files line by line and changing an `8` to an `11`.

The easiest method is using Java installer. From this **Ask Ubuntu Q&A**: [Setting JDK 7 as default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272187/setting-jdk-7-as-default/272190)

> To get a list of your installed Java platforms, run the following command from the terminal:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

> This will give you a list output similar to this:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).
   Selection    Path                                           Priority   Status
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/java         1070      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1051      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1069      manual mode
Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest place to set this is in .bashrc which can be done quickly this way:

`echo JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/ >> .bashrc`

This will make it the last line read as bash initializes and should ensure that JAVA_HOME is correctly set. If you need to do something more complicated you'll want to read up a bit on how terminal initializes. I'd recommend you start by google-ing bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading these answers in the link. They are regarding making environment variable changes persistent. I think whats happening is after you close the terminal they are reverting. Here's the link:
[Make Environment variable changes persist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887442/how-to-permanently-set-an-environment-variable)