# JAVA_HOME exporting issue while installing jep through pip3

Tags: python, java, 19.10, openjdk, pip

I am trying to install **jep** system-wide from pip3 by the following command

```
sudo pip3 install jep
```

I get the following error:

```
 Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Error:
    Please set the environment variable JAVA_HOME to a path containing the JDK.
```

Command

```
python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-t9lhbx74/jep/
```

I have already installed openjdk-14 using apt because jep supports Java => 1.3.
My **bashrc** has the following lines:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/
```

Then I tried to reconfigure java by using

```
    sudo update-alternatives --config java
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/bin/java.
Nothing to configure.
```

I tried solution from follwoing questions but no luck:

[Question 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137805/cant-reset-my-java-home-to-new-open-jdk-11-java-installation)

[Question 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005437/greping-all-files-for-a-string-takes-a-long-time/1005438#1005438)

Here are some helpful details if requried:

1. Ubuntu 19.10
2. Python3 = 3.8 default (3.7 also available being used application specific)
3. pip3 = pip 19.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
4. Java = openjdk 14-ea 2020-03-17
   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14-ea+18-Ubuntu-1)
   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14-ea+18-Ubuntu-1, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: `sudo` does an `env_reset` by default - you can try `sudo --preserve-env=JAVA_HOME pip3 install jep` or switch to an interactive root shell and export the variable there

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I can't mark your comment as an answer.