# What Is Wrong with My Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am using the latest version of Ubuntu (22.4). I installed Anaconda. When I run it, I see a few errors, but the the Anaconda navigator launches and I can use Jupyter Notebook (I can run Python codes too).
According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71010343/cannot-load-swrast-and-iris-drivers-in-fedora-35/72200748#72200748), running matplotlib should cause an error, but for me it does not.
Please take a look at this image:

[image: Error Message]

I am confused, because I have no idea what is going on and I am worried that it might cause problems in the future. Does anyone know what is going on and what I can do to take care of these problems?

Comment: FYI, the latest version of Ubuntu is 23.10 (released today), and the latest LTS is 22.04 (released in April 2022). Ubuntu 20.04 LTS was released in April 2020. While still supported, it is not the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: The 1st line suggest you need to install iris.dri.so See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352158/libgl-error-failed-to-load-drivers-iris-and-swrast-in-ubuntu-20-04 for a similar one.

Comment: @Rinzwind I already had tried that. Did not make any difference.