# Terminal is not picking up new PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable from .profile

Tags: command-line, .profile

### tl;dr version

I added:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
```

to `~/.profile` and saved the file, closed and re-opened Terminal and `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` gave me a blank line.

### Details

I am very new to Linux and Ubuntu.

I am using Terminal to run `cargo install cargo-embed`.  I got an error:

```
Unable to find libudev: 
pkg-config exited with status code 1
> PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_LIBS=1 PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_CFLAGS=1 pkg-config --libs --cflags libudev

The system library `libudev` required by crate `hidapi` was not found.
The file `libudev.pc` needs to be installed and the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable must contain its parent directory.
The PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable is not set.

HINT: if you have installed the library, try setting PKG_CONFIG_PATH to the directory containing `libudev.pc`.
```

I have installed the library so I tried to set PKG_CONFIG_PATH.

First, I ran `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to confirm and got a blank line.
Then I ran `gedit ~/.profile` as suggested in [an answer about setting environment variables permanently.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887442/how-to-permanently-set-an-environment-variable)  At the end of the file, I added:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
```

and saved the file.  I then ran `source ~/.profile` and re-ran `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to confirm and got

```
/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

I then accidentally closed the terminal window and when I opened a new one and tried `cargo install cargo-embed` I got the same error.  I ran `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` again and got a blank line.

If I run `source ~/.profile` it imports but when I close and re-open Terminal it's not there.  I tried just adding `echo "Test"` near the start of the `.profile` file to see if it's running.  I see it when I run `source ~/.profile` but I don't see it when I open the Terminal.  But then I don't know if I should see it.  Like, I said, I'm very new to Ubuntu

### Clarification

I have got past the cargo installation problem.  I'd still like to know why this didn't work and how to add an environment variable permanently.

Comment: You seem to want to add it to the `~/.bashrc` file instead ... based on your expectations

Comment: *How* did you install the library? if you installed the `libudev-dev` development package from the Ubuntu repository then its .pc file should be in the default pc_path (which you can examine with `pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config`) - it shouldn't be necessary to use the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable here at all.

Comment: @steeldriver - I did get past that.  The question is why didn't the environment variable work.

Comment: OK so your terminal emulator likely invokes a *non-login* interactive shell, which (as @Raffa points out) reads your .bashrc not .profile - see for example [Why isn't .profile sourced when opening a terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566399/why-isnt-profile-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal)

Comment: @Raffa - yep, that was it.  Linux people do like to make things difficult for the beginner, don't they?  :-)

Comment: :D … "meticulous" is the word I guess … I too hear things about Linux people, but over my short stay here of 4 years I found they seem to "oddly enough" mostly  favor simplicity with practicality over sophistication … Welcome to AskUbuntu.com

Comment: @Raffa Thanks. Deffo wasn't having a go at anyone here, more at the person who decided that .bashrc was a name which clearly communicated its intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Raffa stated in their comment, I should've been using `~/.bashrc` instead of `~/.profile`.